# Existential Quantification over Values

Tags: scala, types, existential-type

I came across existential quantification over values in the Scala Language
Specification (3.2.10 Existential Types).

```
x: y.Inner forSome{val y : Outer}
```

Does someone have illustrative use cases for it?

`T forSome {val x: S}` is defined as `T forSome { type t <: S with Singleton }`. The Singletron trait is mentioned in the Specification (3.2.1 Singleton Types) but I could not find it in the Scaladoc. Where is it defined?

Comment: Apart from the Singleton case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292274/what-is-an-existential-type

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is useful along with inner classes as alluded in the type names. See for example the Graph and Node classes defined in [A Tour of Scala: Inner Classes](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/115). Existential quantification over a value is used to write the type of the nodes of some unspecified graph.

```
type SomeNode = g.Node forSome { val g: Graph }
```

This might be useful if you wanted to have a method that took two nodes as arguments that had to come from the same graph.

```
def somethingWithTwoNodes[N <: g.Node forSome { val g: Graph }](n1: N, n2: N) = (n1,n2)
```

Note that 2.7 will not accept that method definition because it thinks there's some sort of recursion in N.

Then if you have

```
val g1 = new Graph
val g2 = new Graph
```

then these compile

```
somethingWithTwoNodes(g1.newNode, g1.newNode)
somethingWithTwoNodes(g2.newNode, g2.newNode)
```

but these doesn't

```
somethingWithTwoNodes(g1.newNode, g2.newNode)
somethingWithTwoNodes(g2.newNode, g1.newNode)
```

As for the Singleton trait, it's not really defined in the typical way, i.e. there isn't a class file for it. It's like the types Any, AnyVal, AnyRef and Null. It is defined in `src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/symtab/Definitions.scala` along with these other types, but I doubt that is very useful information to have. It's also an odd beast being a final trait which means you can't mix it in when defining a trait or class, it's really more of a marker that the compiler ascribes to a type to say that it is unique from any other type.

Comment: Thanks. Any ideas where Singleton is defined?

Comment: Isn't it named `Path dependent types` ?

Answer (score 0):

The first half of [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.45.4741) uses this technique to build a stream type.