# Sample of `forSome { val `?

Tags: scala, existential-type, path-dependent-type

Scala Language Specification specifies syntax of [Existential Types](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#existential-types) as

```
Type               ::= InfixType ExistentialClauses
ExistentialClauses ::= ‘forSome’ ‘{’ ExistentialDcl
                       {semi ExistentialDcl} ‘}’
ExistentialDcl     ::= ‘type’ TypeDcl
                    |  ‘val’ ValDcl
```

I have seen a lot code use `forSome` and `type` together, e.g.

```
List[T] forSome { type T; }
```

But I have never seen `forSome` with `val`, is there any sample?

Comment: Related question [Existential Quantification over Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191142/existential-quantification-over-values)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you think about it, you'll soon realize that the only time values appear in types is wit path dependent types. By example:

```
trait Trait {
  val x: { type T }
  val y: x.T // path dependent type: here comes our val
}
```

Applying this to existential types we can now easily cook up a *sample of `forSome { val`*:

```
type SomeList = List[v.T] forSome { val v : { type T }; }
```

The above type denotes any list whose elements are of a path dependent type `v.T`.

By example:

```
object X { 
  type T = String
  val x: T = "hello" 
}
val l1: SomeList = List(X.x) // compiles fine
val l2: SomeList = List(123) // does not compile
```

Granted, `SomeList` is pretty useless as is. As often, such an existential type would only be really useful as part of a bigger type.

Comment: Thank you but sorry, I still can't understand. Why `X.x` is conform to `v.T forSome { val v : { type T }; }`? Does `X.x` has the member `type T`? But from `type T = String; val x:T="hello"`, I can't see `x` has `{type T}`.

Comment: It is not that `X.x` **has** the member `type T`, but rather that it **is** of type `T`. Here `X` (an `object` or in other words a value) corresponds to `v` in our type dependent type. In addition `X.x` has the type `X.T`. So it is clearly true that `X.x` satisfies the type `v.T`, given that `X` is definitely *some* value.

Comment: Self-correction: I meant "path dependent type" rather than "type dependent type"