# How to understand the type name requirement for existential type?

Tags: scala, type-systems, existential-type

From this question: [Sample of `forSome { val `?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741372/sample-of-forsome-val)

I learnt that, if I use this format of existential type:

```
type SomeList = List[v.T] forSome { val v : { type T }; }
```

There must be a type named `T` in the code.

But this code:

```
List[T] forSome { type T }
```

Although there is a `{ type T }` as well, but it doesn't require a type named `T` exist, instead, it can match any type.

I can't understand why there is such difference, and can I expect the `{ type T }` parts of two kinds have the exact same meaning?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'll have a try (though existential types are quite new to me too...)

Your first example uses a path-dependent type `v.T`, and means "given a value v containing a type called T, construct the type of List whose elements have type (`v.T`)".

Your second example

```
List[T] forSome { type T }
```

means "a list of type T where T could be any type", and is equivalent  to:

```
List[_]
```

(The compiler actually gives the type as `List[_]` in Eclipse. David R. MacIver's [article](http://www.drmaciver.com/2008/03/existential-types-in-scala/) discusses this in more detail.)

so probably isn't very useful unless you add additional bounds to the type T

In the first example we are referring to a very specific named (path-dependent) type; In the [answer to your linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741372/sample-of-forsome-val), `T` must exist and be bound to a concrete type, because we use it to access a value of that type:

```
object X { 
  type T = String
  val x: T = "hello" 
}
```

in the second example, we are referring to any type at all.

I think the different meaning of the same syntax is due to the different context (path-dependent type or plain type).

See also :

- http://www.drmaciver.com/2008/03/existential-types-in-scala/
- [What is and when to use Scala's forSome keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21226004/what-is-and-when-to-use-scalas-forsome-keyword)
- [Lower type bound on Scala field in mutable, covariant class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858910/lower-type-bound-on-scala-field-in-mutable-covariant-class)