# Universal quantification in generic function type

Tags: scala, types, type-theory, parametric-polymorphism

Reading the [paper](http://lucacardelli.name/Papers/OnUnderstanding.A4.pdf) on Types and Polymorphism in programming languages, i wondered is it possible to express the similar universal quantification on type members with Scala. Example from the paper:

```
type GenericID = ∀A.A ↦ A
```

Which is a type for generic identity function and the following example in their paper language **Fun** was correct:

```
value inst = fun(f: ∀a.a ↦ a) (f[Int], f[Bool])
value intId = fst(inst(id))   // return a function Int ↦ Int
```

Is there some way to express the similar thing in Scala?

This is not the same as type constructor `type GenericId[A] = A => A`, cause it's a type operation when `∀A.A ↦ A` is a type for generic function

Comment: Try: `type Gen[+_] = _ => _`

Answer (score 2):

Following on from my comment above:

```
scala> type Gen[+_] = _ => _
defined type alias Gen

scala> def f(x: List[Int]): Gen[List[Int]] = x map (y => s"{$y!$y}")
f: (x: List[Int])Gen[List[Int]]

scala> f(List(1, 4, 9))
res0: Function1[_, Any] = List({1!1}, {4!4}, {9!9})
```

In other words, identity of types has not been preserved by `Gen[+_] = _ => _`.

**Addendum**

```
scala> type Identity[A] = A => A
defined type alias Identity

scala> def f(x: List[Int]): Identity[List[Int]] = x => x.reverse
f: (x: List[Int])List[Int] => List[Int]

scala> f(List(1, 4, 9))
res1: List[Int] => List[Int] = <function1>

scala> def g(x: List[Int]): Identity[List[Int]] = x => x map (y => s"{$y!$y}")
<console>:35: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[String]
 required: List[Int]
       def g(x: List[Int]): Identity[List[Int]] = x => x map (y => s"{$y!$y}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try: `type Gen[+_] = _ => _`

```
scala> def f(x:List[Int]):Gen[List[Int]] = x.reverse
f: (x: List[Int])Gen[List[Int]]

scala> f(List(3,4))
res0: Function1[_, Any] = List(4, 3)

scala> def f(x:List[Number]):Gen[List[Number]] = x.reverse
f: (x: List[Number])Gen[List[Number]]

scala> f(List(3,4))
res1: Function1[_, Any] = List(4, 3)
```

Comment: I don't think your example quite does what it seems to. Every instance of `_` in `Gen[+_] = _ => _` are separately quantified. If you use a real type parameter, say `A`, you'll find it won't compile unless you remove the covariance annotation.