# How to use a protocol with associative type as return value in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics

I'm trying to use a protocol with associated type as return value of a class func.

[Another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24708890/why-can-this-protocol-only-be-used-as-a-generic-constraint) here on stackoverflow is about the same question and based on this post's answer I tried the following:

```
// addArg takes a single Int argument and returns something, 
// which is capable of adding a another Int argument
class OpWithNoArg {
    func addArg<OP: OpWithOneArg where OP.ArgType == Int>(arg: Int) -> OP {
        return OpWithOneArgImpl() // (1) error here !
    }
}

// a protocol with associated type, which allows adding another
// argument of a not yet specified type
protocol OpWithOneArg {
    typealias ArgType
    func addAnotherArg(arg: ArgType)
}

// an implementation of the protocol above, 
// which fixes the associated type to an Int
class OpWithOneArgImpl : OpWithOneArg {
    typealias ArgType = Int
    func addAnotherArg(arg: Int) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The error in Xcode 7.0 Beta 4 on line marked with (1) is

> cannot convert return expression of type 'OpWithOneArgImpl' to
>   expected return type 'OP'

If I change the return value to an optional and `nil` is returned, the sample compiles successfully:

```
// return null  
class OpWithNoArg {
    func addArg<OP: OpWithOneArg where OP.ArgType == Int>(arg: Int) -> OP? {
        // return OpWithOneArgImpl()
        return nil
    }
}
```

Is this way of using a protocol with associative type as return value possible in swift, and if that's the case, how can the compiler error mentioned above be fixed?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

In Java, the code would be something like the following snippet. I try to find a way in Swift to achieve the same.

```
class C {
    <T> P<T> f(T arg) {
        return new PImpl();
    }
}

interface P<S> {
    void g(S arg);
}

class PImpl<S> implements P<S> {
    PImpl() {}
    public void g(S arg) {}
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/27406808. Basically, `OP` is not "`OpWithOneArg` with a type of `Int`", it's whatever you use the result when it is called. Such a type might not be convertible from `OpWithOneArgImpl`, so it doesn't let you.

Comment: Your link contains a very useful explanation! A must-read for people like me with heavy Java background ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not clear what you are trying to achieve, but imho the error stems from the fact that in your `addArg` function you define a generic type `OP` which should be typically used in the function's arguments and body.

Instead you return a non generic type trying to force it to be treated as a generic `OP.

A quick fix could be a force cast to `OP` of your return object:

```
return OpWithOneArgImpl() as !OP
```

but I wouldn't recommend it.

In your example your `addArg` will always return a `OpWithOneArgImpl` thus it could just be defined as a `func addArg(arg: Int) -> OpWithOneArgImpl`

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

Probably this is not what you're trying to achieve, but hope it can help 
with a clearer explanation of what I intended above.

```
protocol OpWithOneArg {
    typealias ArgType
    func addAnotherArg(arg: ArgType)
    init() // Must have a init with no argument
}


class OpWithOneArgImpl : OpWithOneArg {
    typealias ArgType = Int
    func addAnotherArg(arg: Int) {
        // ...
    }
    required init() {
        // init implementation
    }
}

class OpWithNoArg {
    func addArgWithOPType<OP: OpWithOneArg where OP.ArgType == Int>(op: OP.Type, arg: Int) -> OP {
        return OP() // Here we use the init
    }
}

let foo = OpWithNoArg()
foo.addArgWithOPType(OpWithOneArgImpl.self, arg: 3)
```

**Edit:**

Maybe you might investigate the use of generic types:

```
protocol OpWithOneArg {
    typealias ArgType
    func addAnotherArg(arg: ArgType)
    init() // Must have a init with no argument
}


class OpWithOneArgImpl<T> : OpWithOneArg { // Generic implementation confirming to protocol
    typealias ArgType = T
    func addAnotherArg(arg: T) {
        // ...
    }
    required init() {
        // init implementation
    }
}


class OpWithNoArg {
    func addArgWithOPType<OP: OpWithOneArg>(op: OP.Type, arg: OP.ArgType) -> OP {
        return OP() // Here we use the init
    }
}

let foo = OpWithNoArg()

// OpWithOneArgImpl<Int>
foo.addArgWithOPType(OpWithOneArgImpl.self, arg: 3) 

// OpWithOneArgImpl<String>
foo.addArgWithOPType(OpWithOneArgImpl.self, arg: "Hello")
```

Comment: I added a Java code sample in my post, which shows, what I try to do in Swift :)

Comment: Ups ... sorry I'not proficient in Java :( maybe someone else could help

Comment: Using the force cast solves the compiler error, however, invoking the functions didn't work as expected: `OpWithNoArg().addArg(42).addAnotherArg(35)`  results in a compiler error _cannot invoke 'addAnotherArg' with an argument list of type '(Int)'_

Comment: Currently my implemention looks like your suggestion: `func addArg(arg: Int) -> OpWithOneArgImpl`, however - as in Java you always try to introduce interfaces - I'm trying to get rid of returning a concret implementation and return a protocol / interface instead. But maybe that's not the Swift way :)

Comment: You might think of `OP` as a _placeholder_ for a type used by the compiler. This explains why force cast don't work: the compiler don't know what `OP` actually should be. With the other solution compiler knows at compile time what type is returned.