# Scala: Generic method composing

Tags: scala, generics

I have just started learning scala and I am pretty confused with Generics:

**Question 1:**

```
def getRemainingItem[X](list : List[X], fun : (X) => Boolean) : List[X] = {
    list.filterNot(fun)
}
```

What is X here looks like E of Java(This code works fine)

**Question 2:**

```
def getRemainingItem(list : List[Any], fun : (Any) => Boolean) : List[Any] = {
    list.filterNot(fun)
}
```

Why is Any not working. I am thinking Any can accept any type (this isn't compiling)

**Question 3:**

```
def getRemainingItem(list : List[_], fun : (_) => Boolean) : List[_] = {
    list.filterNot(fun)
}
```

Again this is not working and what is the difference between "_" and "Any"

Comment: `What is X here looks like E of Java(This code works fine)` What `E`?

Comment: `2` compiles just fine.

Comment: The underscores in the a time parameter position means some unknown time. So, `List[_]` and `(_) => Boolean`, the `_`s are not known,therefore not necessarily the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer 1**: X is a *generic type parameter*. So method `getRemainingItem` is a *generic method* which will be called with a *concrete type argument* (a *type instantiation* such as `X = Int`).

**Answer 2**: that code snippet does compile (tested with Scala 2.11)

**Answer 3**: a type `T[_]` is a shortcut for `T[X] forSome { type X }` (which is an *existential type*). This is similar to Java *wildcards* (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html). Of course, saying "some unknown type T" is different from saying "Any" (which is a concrete type -- the top type).

For more information:
- [What is an existential type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292274/what-is-an-existential-type)