# Java language specification on wildcards

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, jls, unbounded-wildcard

I am going through this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5) (Chapter 4. Types, Values, and Variables) and did not understand below point:

> The relationship of wildcards to established type theory is an interesting one, which we briefly allude to here. Wildcards are a restricted form of existential types. `Given a generic type declaration G<T extends B>, G<?> is roughly analogous to Some X <: B. G<X>`.

I appreciate if you provide good example to understand above point clearly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wording and formatting of this statement are a bit unlucky<sup>*</sup>. The link in the [answer by Maouven](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35579224/3182664) actually covers the general topic pretty well, but one can try to focus on the particular case of Java and Wildcards here:

> Wildcards are a restricted form of existential types. Given a generic type declaration G, G is roughly analogous to Some X <: B. G.

This basically says that the type parameter of the `G` is any subtype of `B`. And this is *always* the case, even when you don't say it explicitly.

Consider the following snippet, which hopefully illustrates the point:

```
class B { } 
class G<T extends B> 
{
    T get() { return null; }
}

public class Example
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        G<?> g = null;

        // This works, even though "G<?>" seemingly does not say 
        // anything about the type parameter:
        B b = g.get();
    }
}
```

The object that you obtain by calling `g.get()` is of type `B`, because the **declaration** of `G<T extends B>` guarantees that any type parameter (even if it is the `?` wildcard) always be "at least" of type `B`.

(In contrast to that: If the declaration only was `G<T>`, then the type obtained from `g.get()` would only be of type `Object`)

---

The relationship is described as "*roughly analogous*" to the type theoretic notation. You can probably imagine this as saying: If the declaration is `G<T extends B>`, and you use the type `G<?>`, then this roughly (!) means: There exists a type `X extends B`, and the `?` here stands for this (unknown) type `X`.

---

An aside: Note that this also refers to [Insersection Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.9). If you declared the class as `class G<T extends B & Runnable>`, then the statements

```
B b = g.get();
Runnable x = g.get();
```

would both be valid.

---

<sup>*</sup> The "unlucky" formatting referred to the fact that the source code of this paragraph actually reads

```
    ... is roughly analogous to <span class="type">Some <span class="type">X</span> ...
```

making clearer that the word "Some" already is part of the *type* that is being defined there formally...

Answer (score 0):

Wildcards are a restricted form of existential types, in the way they incorporate the principle of existential types in Java. You can refer to the link here which provide explanatory examples:
[What is an existential type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292274/what-is-an-existential-type)