# Scala Universal vs Existential type confusion

Tags: java, scala, existential-type

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292274/what-is-an-existential-type/5520212#5520212) it says...

```
  // Universal types let you write things like:

  def combine[T](source: List[T], dest: List[T]): List[T] = {
    source ++ dest
  }
```

But I did not understand the explanation.

Can someone explain the difference between the universal type example above and some of the similar examples (which contain existential types) below?

```
  def combine2[_](source: List[_], dest: List[_]): List[_] = {
    source ++ dest
  }


  def combine3(source: List[_], dest: List[_]): List[_] = {
    source ++ dest
  }

  def combine4[A, B](source: List[A], dest: List[B]): List[_] = {
    source ++ dest
  }

  def combine5[T](source: List[T], dest: List[T] forSome {type T}): List[T] forSome {type T} = {
    source ++ dest
  }
```

Java for good measure...

```
public static List<?> combine6(final List<?> source, final List<?> dest) {
    return source;
}

// Why doesn't this compile? 
public static <T> List<T> combine7(final List<?> source, final List<?> dest) {
    return source;
}
```

Also, if I provide typetags, does that in any way replace the need for existential types?

```
  def combineTypetag[A, B, C](source: List[A], dest: List[B]) 
  (implicit tagA: TypeTag[A], tagB: TypeTag[B], tagC: TypeTag[C]): List[C] = {
    source ++ dest
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`combine` says that if you have two lists with the same element type, you get the same type back, e.g.:

```
val list1: List[Int] = ...
val list2: List[Int] = ...
val list3 = combine(list1, list2) // also List[Int]
val x = list3.head // Int
val y = x + x // Int
```

`combine` can also be used with lists of *different* types, and return the most precise common type:

```
val list1: List[FileInputStream] = ...
val list2: List[ByteArrayInputStream] = ...
val list3 = combine(list1, list2) // List[InputStream]
```

All the other options return `List[T] forSome {type T}`, i.e. list of some unknown type (`List[_]` is just a short way to write this):

```
val list1: List[Int] = ...
val list2: List[Int] = ...
val list4 = combine2(list1, list2) // List[_]
val z = list4.head // Any
val w = z + z // doesn't compile
```

So they simply lose the type information. Only use existential types when you *can't* be any more precise.

> Why doesn't this compile?

If it did, what would you expect to happen here:

```
List<?> list = Arrays.asList("a", "b");
List<Integer> list2 = <Integer>combine7(list, list);
```

?

> Also, if I provide typetags, does that in any way replace the need for existential types?

There is no need for existential types here, but when there is, type tags won't help: the compiler by definition can only insert type tags when it knows what the static types are, so that existential types aren't needed.

Comment: Can I think of existential types as "don't know" types. For example, source: List[_] means that source is of type List["don't know"].

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what they are. And of course, if you have multiple `List[_]`, those `_` can be different. And even when you as programmer know they are the same, the compiler doesn't (in general).