# How do I type parameterize a tuple?

Tags: typescript

I have a tuple where the types relate to each other. In my case it's an extractor function that extracts a value that is in turn used as input to another function.

Conceptually what I'm looking for is something like this, but this doesn't compile:

```
const a: <T>[(v:any) => T, (t:T) => void] = [ ... ]
```

The use case is this. I have an incoming RPC message of type `any`, and an API with well known argument types. I want to build a "wiring plan" that takes two arguments, one extractor function and the corresponding API function.

```
export interface API = {
    saveModel : (model:Model)    => Promise<boolean>,
    getModel  : (modelID:string) => Promise<Model>,
}

const api: API = { ... }

// this is the tuple type where i'd like to define that
// there's a relation between the second and third member
// of the tuple.
type WirePlan = [[string, (msg:any) => T, (t:T) => Promise<any>]]

const wirePlan: WirePlan = [[
  ['saveModel', (msg:any) => <Model>msg.model   , api.saveModel],
  ['getModel' , (msg:any) => <string>msg.modelID, api.getModel],
]

const handleMessage = (msg) => {
  const handler = wirePlan.find((w) => w[0] === msg.name)
  const extractedValue = handler[1](msg)
  return handler[2](extractedValue)
}
```

I can work around the issue in other ways, it just struck me there may be something about tuples I haven't understood.

Comment: Posting imaginary syntax isn't very helpful - can you show how you would use this `a` value, i.e. examples which you'd like to be legal and examples which you'd like to be illegal?

Comment: Ok. I flesh it out with a concrete example.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question but is this might be helpfull? `type getSet<T> = [()=>T,(val:T)=>T]`

Comment: @ThomasDevries that could be a way.

Answer (score 6):

> Conceptually what I'm looking for is something like this, but this doesn't compile:
>
> ```
> const a: <T>[(v:any) => T, (t:T) => void] = [ ... ]
> ```

That is, in fact, the *opposite* of what you want. Drawing on the intuition of function types, `a: <T>(t: T) => T` means you have a function that works for *all* types. This is a universal quantifier: the implementation of `a` doesn't know what `T` is; the user of `a` can set `T` to whatever they want. Doing this for your tuple would be disastrous, as the inner functions need to output values of `T` no matter what `T` is, and therefore the only thing they can do is error out/loop forever/be bottom in some way or another (they must return `never`).

You want [existential quantification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292274/what-is-an-existential-type). `a: ∃T. [(v:any) => T, (t:T) => void]` means that `a` has some type `T` associated with it. The implementation of `a` knows what it is and can do whatever it likes with it, but the user of `a` now knows nothing about it. In effect, it reverses the roles when compared to universal quantification. [TypeScript doesn't have support for existential types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466) (not even in a super basic form like Java's wildcards), but it [can be simulated](https://gist.github.com/pelotom/62aaadac9a12b424a49e2db6341d6903):

```
type WirePlanEntry = <R>(user: <T>(name: string, reader: (msg: any) => T, action: (t: T) => Promise<any>)) => R
type WirePlan = WirePlanEntry[]
```

Yes, that is a mouthful. It can be decomposed to:

```
// Use universal quantification for the base type
type WirePlanEntry<T> = [string, (msg: any) => T, (t: T) => Promise<any>]
// A WirePlanEntryConsumer<R> takes WirePlanEntry<T> for any T, and outputs R
type WirePlanEntryConsumer<R> = <T>(plan: WirePlanEntry<T>) => R
// This consumer consumer consumes a consumer by giving it a `WirePlanEntry<T>`
// The type of an `EWirePlanEntry` doesn't give away what that `T` is, so now we have
// a `WirePlanEntry` of some unknown type `T` being passed to a consumer.
// This is the essence of existential quantification.
type EWirePlanEntry = <R>(consumer: WirePlanEntryConsumer<R>) => R
// this is an application of the fact that the statement
// "there exists a T for which the statement P(T) is true"
// implies that
// "not for every T is the statement P(T) false"

// Convert one way
function existentialize<T>(e: WirePlanEntry<T>): EWirePlanEntry {
  return <R>(consumer: WirePlanEntryConsumer<R>) => consumer(e)
}

// Convert the other way
function lift<R>(consumer: WirePlanEntryConsumer<R>): (e: EWirePlanEntry) => R {
  return (plan: EWirePlanEntry) => plan(consumer)
}
```

Consuming `EWirePlanEntry` looks like

```
plan(<T>(eT: WirePlanEntry<T>) => ...)
// without types
plan(eT => ...)
```

but if you just have consumers like

```
function consume<T>(plan: WirePlanEntry<T>): R // R is not a function of T
```

you'll use them like

```
plan(consume) // Backwards!
lift(consume)(plan) // Forwards!
```

Now, though, you can have producers. The simplest such producer has already been written: `existentialize`.

Here's the rest of your code:

```
type WirePlan = EWirePlanEntry[]
const wirePlan: WirePlan = [
  existentialize(['saveModel', (msg:any) => <Model>msg.model   , api.saveModel]),
  existentialize(['getModel' , (msg:any) => <string>msg.modelID, api.getModel ]),
]

const handleMessage = (msg: any) => {
  let entry = wirePlan.find(lift((w) => w[0] === msg.name))
  if(entry) {
    entry(handler => {
      const extractedValue = handler[1](msg)
      return handler[2](extractedValue)
    })
  }
}
```

[In Action](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%2F%2F%20Use%20universal%20quantification%20for%20the%20base%20type%0D%0Atype%20WirePlanEntry<T>%20%3D%20%5Bstring%2C%20(msg%3A%20any)%20%3D>%20T%2C%20(t%3A%20T)%20%3D>%20Promise<any>%5D%0D%0A%2F%2F%20A%20WirePlanEntryConsumer<R>%20takes%20WirePlanEntry<T>%20for%20any%20T%2C%20and%20outputs%20R%0D%0Atype%20WirePlanEntryConsumer<R>%20%3D%20<T>(plan%3A%20WirePlanEntry<T>)%20%3D>%20R%0D%0A%2F%2F%20This%20consumer%20consumer%20consumes%20a%20consumer%20by%20giving%20it%20a%20%60WirePlanEntry<T>%60%0D%0A%2F%2F%20The%20type%20of%20an%20%60EWirePlanEntry%60%20doesn't%20give%20away%20what%20that%20%60T%60%20is%2C%20so%20now%20we%20have%0D%0A%2F%2F%20a%20%60WirePlanEntry%60%20of%20some%20unknown%20type%20%60T%60%20being%20passed%20to%20a%20consumer.%0D%0A%2F%2F%20This%20is%20the%20essence%20of%20existential%20quantification.%0D%0Atype%20EWirePlanEntry%20%3D%20<R>(consumer%3A%20WirePlanEntryConsumer<R>)%20%3D>%20R%0D%0A%2F%2F%20this%20is%20an%20application%20of%20the%20fact%20that%20the%20statement%0D%0A%2F%2F%20"there%20exists%20a%20T%20for%20which%20the%20statement%20P(T)%20is%20true"%0D%0A%2F%2F%20implies%20that%0D%0A%2F%2F%20"not%20for%20every%20T%20is%20the%20statement%20P(T)%20false"%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Convert%20one%20way%0D%0Afunction%20existentialize<T>(e%3A%20WirePlanEntry<T>)%3A%20EWirePlanEntry%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20<R>(consumer%3A%20WirePlanEntryConsumer<R>)%20%3D>%20consumer(e)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Convert%20the%20other%20way%0D%0Afunction%20lift<R>(consumer%3A%20WirePlanEntryConsumer<R>)%3A%20(e%3A%20EWirePlanEntry)%20%3D>%20R%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20(plan%3A%20EWirePlanEntry)%20%3D>%20plan(consumer)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20placeholder%0D%0Atype%20Model%20%3D%20string%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20API%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20saveModel%20%3A%20(model%3AModel)%20%20%20%20%3D>%20Promise<boolean>%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getModel%20%20%3A%20(modelID%3Astring)%20%3D>%20Promise<Model>%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alet%20api%20%3D%20%7B%7D%20as%20API%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20WirePlan%20%3D%20EWirePlanEntry%5B%5D%0D%0Aconst%20wirePlan%3A%20WirePlan%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20existentialize(%5B'saveModel'%2C%20(msg%3Aany)%20%3D>%20<Model>msg.model%20%20%20%2C%20api.saveModel%5D)%2C%0D%0A%20%20existentialize(%5B'getModel'%20%2C%20(msg%3Aany)%20%3D>%20<string>msg.modelID%2C%20api.getModel%20%5D)%2C%0D%0A%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20handleMessage%20%3D%20(msg%3A%20any)%20%3D>%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20let%20entry%20%3D%20wirePlan.find(lift((w)%20%3D>%20w%5B0%5D%20%3D%3D%3D%20msg.name))%0D%0A%20%20if(entry)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20entry(handler%20%3D>%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20extractedValue%20%3D%20handler%5B1%5D(msg)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20handler%5B2%5D(extractedValue)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)