# Function returning result of any constructor of a GADT

Tags: haskell, typing, gadt

I'm currently having a fight with the typechecker when I try to create a function returning `Thing a` (where `Thing` is a GADT). A minimal contrived example:

```
{-#LANGUAGE GADTs, EmptyDataDecls #-}
module Main where

-- Define a contrived GADT
data TFoo
data TBar
data Thing a where
  Foo :: Int -> Thing TFoo
  Bar :: String -> Thing TBar

combine :: [Thing a]
combine = [Foo 1, Bar "abc"]

main :: IO ()
main = undefined
```

The typechecker gets unhappy that `a` doesn't match `TBar`. Presumably this is because it has already inferred that `a` is `TFoo`. But, this is surprising, because with regular sum types you can do:

```
data Thing = Foo Int | Bar String

combine :: [Thing]
combine = [Foo 1, Bar "abc"]
```

Is there anyway to return a type parametric over the GADT parameter?

Outside of the context of the contrived examples, I need GADTs so I can type certain functions to only take a `Foo`, but before that I need to also be able to just return a list of `Thing`s.

Comment: I think your problem is that lists must be homogeneous. Like you noted, you can have `[Thing]`, but you can't but two different `Thing a`'s in the same list.

Comment: @jkeuhlen Right. That makes sense for clearly disparate types like `[1, "a"]`, but I'm a little confused with the parity between GADTs and sum types. Is `Thing a` not the "final return type" of `Foo` and `Bar`. Is there any type that encompass the result of both `Foo 1` and `Bar "abc"`?

Comment: No, `Thing a` is *not* the final return type of your constructors. They explicitly create a `Thing TFOO` and a `Thing TBar`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got your quantifiers mixed up.

```
combine :: [Thing a]
```

means (the `forall` is implicit in the syntax)

```
combine :: forall a. [Thing a]
```

Essentially, `combine` needs to be a `[Thing a]` no matter what `a` is, because `a` is chosen by the code that calls `combine`. Or, in another sense,

```
-- psuedo-Haskell
combine :: (a :: *) -> [Thing a]
```

`combine` is a function that takes a type as argument and promises to construct a list of `Things` of that type. The only possible definition of `combine` with this type signature is `combine = []`, plus a bunch of dumb ones like `[undefined]`, etc. E.g. `combine = [Foo 1]` would not work either, because `a` is not being inferred, because it's not `combine` that sets `a`; it's the user.

You want

```
-- psuedo-Haskell
combine :: [exists a. Thing a]
```

which means "`combine` is a list of things, and each thing is a `Thing` of some unknown type" (and every `Thing` can be of a different type). The `exists` quantifier is the flipside of `forall`. It means the definition of `combine` can set whatever type it wants and the user will have to deal with it. Haskell doesn't support `exists` out-of-the-box, so you need to define an intermediate data type:

```
data SomeThing = forall a. SomeThing (Thing a)
```

The syntax is a bit backwards for using the universal quantifier to create existential quantification, but the idea is that you get

```
SomeThing :: forall a. Thing a -> SomeThing
```

which essentially erases the knowledge of what `a` is.

You can then have

```
combine :: [SomeThing]
combine = [SomeThing $ Foo 1, SomeThing $ Bar "abc"]
```

Comment: Wow! Fantastic answer. Thank you so much. That works perfectly. It's a bit unfortunate that to get the benefit of GADTs (insofar as you can limit which "children?" are passed into other functions) you now can't use them homogeneously without wrapping. Do you know if `exists` is something that could exist in Haskell in the future or is wrapping just the accepted approach the everyone uses?

Comment: @BaileyParker The accepted approach is just wrapping. Another approach is higher-rankedly-typed continuations (`forall ret. (forall a. Thing a -> ret) -> ret`) ([e.g. this is how you must do it in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46186356/5684257)), but it's a lot more painful than this wrapping (and you still need wrapping because of impredicativity). I don't think there are plans to add `exists` to Haskell because having both `exists` and `forall` would probably make the typechecker too complicated.

Comment: What you call `exist` is called `forall` in a number of attempts to add impredicative polymorphism. All is not lost with the latest proposal on *guarded instantiation*, but implementation is still far from finish, more on this here: https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/ghc-devs/2018-February/015407.html

Comment: @ArtemPelenitsyn Sorry, what? `exists` and `forall` are literally opposites. `[forall a. Show a => a]` means a list of things where each thing can be of any type that satisfies `Show`. The only values of that type are `[]`, `[undefined]`, etc. `[exists a. Show a => a]` means a list of things where each thing has some `Show`able type. This has many values, e.g. `[5, "abc", 'a', [10]]`. For some arbitrary type `A` with `Show A`, `[forall a. Show a => a]` is a subtype of `[A]` is a subtype of `[exists a. Show a => a]`.

Comment: @HTNW don't you know that even ExistentialTypes extensions in GHC use `forall` keyword?

Comment: @ArtemPelenitsyn Yes, I mention that in my answer. But having impredicative polymorphism with `forall` will still not solve the problem. You'd be allowed a `[forall ret. (forall a. Thing a -> ret) -> ret]`, which is isomorphic to `[exists. a Thing a]` and removes the need for a wrapper `data` type, but it is *still* not as simple as just having `exists` as a primitive.

Comment: @ArtemPelenitsyn Or, in other words: `ExistentialTypes` allows for  *non-primitive* existential quantification by using *universal* quantification (thus `forall`) plus some identities between the two. `forall` does not directly cause existential quantification. `forall` always causes universal quantification. It's just that `ExistentialTypes` allows you to use universal quantification in a place where it can be turned inside out to cause existential quantification. But it's not primitive. `forall a. Thing a` is a subtype of `Thing TFoo`, but `Thing TFoo` is not a subtype of `SomeThing`.