# Dynamically pattern matching nested GADT back out of a wrapper

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, typing, gadt

I recently asked how to make a homogenous list of GADT instances: [Function returning result of any constructor of a GADT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49078017/function-returning-result-of-any-constructor-of-a-gadt)

tl;dr

```
{-#LANGUAGE GADTs, EmptyDataDecls #-}
module Main where

-- Define a contrived GADT
data TFoo
data TBar
data Thing a where
  Foo :: Int -> Thing TFoo
  Bar :: String -> Thing TBar

data SomeThing = forall a. SomeThing (Thing a)

combine :: [SomeThing]
combine = [Something $ Foo 1, SomeThing $ Bar "abc"]
```

Now, I'm having some trouble dynamically "unwrapping" them. Let's say we have this (still contrived, but closer to my real use case) code:

```
{-#LANGUAGE GADTs, EmptyDataDecls #-}
module Main where

-- Define a contrived GADT
data Thing a where
  Thing :: TKind a -> Thing a

data TFoo
data TBar
data TKind a where
  Foo :: TKind TFoo
  Bar :: TKind TBar

data SomeThing = forall a. SomeThing (Thing a)

example :: SomeThing
example = SomeThing $ Thing Foo

extractThingWithTKind :: TKind a -> SomeThing -> Either String (Thing a)
extractThingWithTKind k st = case st of
                               SomeThing t@(Thing k) -> Right t
                               _                     -> Left "nope"
```

The above doesn't work because the `t` in `Right t` doesn't have the type `Thing a`. Intrinsically, I understand why this doesn't work. Pattern matching on the `k` doesn't do what I want (only match if the `k` is the same as the one passed in). But this is my best stab at approximating what I want. I tried `instance`ing `Eq` on `TKind a`, but because `(==) :: a -> a -> Bool`, this won't work (the equality depends on potentially disparate types at runtime). I could wrap `TKind` like I did `Thing`, but then I'd just be pushing the problem lower.

Removing the dynamism, I tried just pattern matching out a `Thing TFoo` explicitly:

```
extractThingWithFoo :: SomeThing -> Either String (Thing TFoo)
extractThingWithFoo st = case st of
                            SomeThing t@(Thing Foo) -> Right t
                            _                       -> Left "nope"
```

And that works! But does this mean that I can't do the dynamic matching? It would be a real pain to have to duplicate the above method for each kind `TKind` (in the non-contrived version, there are many). The only other solution I see is changing `SomeThing` to be a sum type that has one wrapper for each `TKind`, but then you're just moving the duplicated code to a different place (and forcing all uses of `SomeThing` to pattern match each).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to implement a function with the signature
`extractThingWithTKind :: TKind a -> SomeThing -> Either String (Thing a)`, we need to be able to decide that what's inside `SomeThing` is a `TKind a` or not. GADT constructors are witnesses of such type equalities, but they need to be explicitly pattern-matched on to "unwrap" these assumptions in the function's local scope.

```
extractThingWithTKind :: TKind a -> SomeThing -> Either String (Thing a)
extractThingWithTKind Foo (SomeThing t@(Thing Foo)) = Right t
extractThingWithTKind Bar (SomeThing t@(Thing Bar)) = Right t
extractThingWithTKind _ _ = Left "nope"
```

Pattern matching on the first argument gives rise to the assumption that `a ~ TFoo` (in the first case), and further pattern matching on the second argument proves that the thing inside `SomeThing` is also a `TFoo`. Crucially, the individual cases have to be spelled out one by one, as it's the constructors themselves that provide the evidence.

Comment: That does it indeed! Thanks for the nice explanation. In hindsight, I guess this is kind of obvious, but I'm still really new to GADTs and still trying to wrap my head around their use. Thanks again :)