# How do you define an array of generics in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, generics

Let's say I have a generic interface like the following:

```
interface Transform<ArgType> {
    transformer: (input: string, arg: ArgType) => string;
    arg: ArgType;
}
```

And then I want to apply an array of these `Transform` to a `string`. How do I define this array of `Transform` such that it validates that `<ArgType>` is equivalent in both `Transform.transformer` and `Transform.arg`? I'd like to write something like this:

```
function append(input: string, arg: string): string {
    return input.concat(arg);
}

function repeat(input: string, arg: number): string {
    return input.repeat(arg);
}

const transforms = [
    {
        transformer: append,
        arg: " END"
    },
    {
        transformer: repeat,
        arg: 4
    },
];

function applyTransforms(input: string, transforms: \*what type goes here?*\): string {
    for (const transform of transforms) {
        input = transform.transformer(input, transform.arg);
    }

    return input;
}
```

In this example, what type do I define `const transforms` as in order for the type system to validate that each item in the array satisfies the generic `Transform<ArgType>` interface?

Comment: I don't think you can do this in 100% type safe way. `Transform<any>[]` will work but it will not be 100% type safe. You may find this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51815782/typescript-array-of-different-generic-types/51816182#51816182

Comment: It's crazy how complicated this needs to be in Typescript.

Answer (score 24):

(Using TS 3.0 in the following)

If TypeScript directly supported [existential types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Existential_types), I'd tell you to use them.  An existential type means something like "all I know is that the type exists, but I don't know or care what it is."  Then your `transforms` parameter have a type like `Array< exists A. Transform<A> >`, meaning "an array of things that are `Transform<A>` for *some* `A`".  There is a [suggestion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466) to allow these types in the language, but few languages support this so who knows.

You could "give up" and just use `Array<Transform<any>>`, which will work but fail to catch inconsistent cases like this:

```
applyTransforms("hey", [{transformer: repeat, arg: "oops"}]); // no error
```

But as you said you're looking to enforce consistency, even in the absence of existential types.  Luckily, there are workarounds, with varying levels of complexity.  Here's one:

---

Let's declare a type function which takes a `T`, and if it a `Transform<A>` for *some* `A`, it returns `unknown` (the new [top type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#new-unknown-top-type) which matches every value... so `unknown & T` is equal to `T` for all `T`), otherwise it returns `never` (the [bottom type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never) which matches no value... so `never & T` is equal to `never` for all `T`):

```
type VerifyTransform<T> = unknown extends
  (T extends { transformer: (input: string, arg: infer A) => string } ?
    T extends { arg: A } ? never : unknown : unknown
  ) ? never : unknown
```

It uses [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) to calculate that.  The idea is that it looks at `transformer` to figure out `A`, and then makes sure that `arg` is compatible with that `A`.

Now we can type `applyTransforms` as a generic function which only accepts a `transforms` parameter which matches an array whose elements of type `T` match `VerifyTransform<T>`:

```
function applyTransforms<T extends Transform<any>>(
  input: string, 
  transforms: Array<T> & VerifyTransform<T>
): string {
  for (const transform of transforms) {
    input = transform.transformer(input, transform.arg);
  }
  return input;
}
```

Here we see it working:

```
applyTransforms("hey", transforms); // okay
```

If you pass in something inconsistent, you get an error:

```
applyTransforms("hey", [{transformer: repeat, arg: "oops"}]); // error
```

The error isn't particularly illuminating: "`[ts] Argument of type '{ transformer: (input: string, arg: number) => string; arg: string; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.`" but at least it's an error.

---

Or, you could realize that if all you're doing is passing `arg` to `transformer`, you can make your existential-like `SomeTransform` type like this:

```
interface SomeTransform {
  transformerWithArg: (input: string) => string;
}
```

and make a `SomeTransform` from any `Transform<A>` you want:

```
const makeSome = <A>(transform: Transform<A>): SomeTransform => ({
  transformerWithArg: (input: string) => transform.transformer(input, transform.arg)
});
```

And then accept an array of `SomeTransform` instead:

```
function applySomeTransforms(input: string, transforms: SomeTransform[]): string {
  for (const someTransform of transforms) {
    input = someTransform.transformerWithArg(input);
  }

  return input;
}
```

See if it works:

```
const someTransforms = [
  makeSome({
    transformer: append,
    arg: " END"
  }),
  makeSome({
    transformer: repeat,
    arg: 4
  }),
];

applySomeTransforms("h", someTransforms);
```

And if you try to do it inconsistently:

```
makeSome({transformer: repeat, arg: "oops"}); // error
```

you get an error which is more reasonable: "`Types of parameters 'arg' and 'arg' are incompatible. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.`"

---

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck.

Comment: What is the purpose of `makeSome` here ? are you just creating a new object of type `SomeTransform` from `Transform<T>` ? in that case the type of `someTransforms` should be `SomeTransform[]` right?

Comment: I think you can simplify `VerifyTransform<T>` to just `type VerifyTransform<T> = (T extends Transform<infer A> ?  unknown : never) ` it seems to work as expected. And although `never` is the logical way to ensure incompatibility, maybe a string literal type will give nicer errors: `type VerifyTransform<T> = (T extends Transform<infer A> ?  unknown : "INconsistent args to Transform<T>") `

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir: that simplification might work... but I've run into the problem where `infer A` ends up inferring an intersection of types (hence the two-step process), or where any one of the types in a union works making the whole thing work, whereas we need all the types to work (hence the never-to-unknown-and-back-again stuff to make one failure give all failures).   I want this to fail: `applyTransforms("hey", [{transformer: repeat, arg: 1}, {transformer: repeat, arg: "oops"}]);`

Comment: @Niladri, yes, that's what I'm doing.

Comment: Clever use of a distributive conditional type to validate that the inferred type of `transforms` is of the form `Transform<A1> | Transform<A2> | ...`!  Of course, there are some limitations with this approach.  It doesn't give you a single type you can write down for `Array< exists A. Transform<A> >`, so AFAIK you don't get automatic type checking of manipulations like appending a transform to an existing array.

Comment: What is the best way to get that type of knowledge? I'd like to focus on advanced typescript, but the documentation itself doesn't explain very deep. Any ideas?

Answer (score 13):

You can do this using the generic tuple rest parameters (added in TS 3.0).

```
type TransformRest<T extends any[]> = {
   [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends T[number] ? Transform<T[P]> : never
}

function applyTransforms<T extends any[]>(input: string, ...transforms: TransformRest<T>): string {
   for (const transform of transforms) {
      input = transform.transformer(input, transform.arg);
   }

   return input;
}

// Makes a tuple from it's arguments, otherwise typescript always types as array
function tuplify<TS extends any[]>(...args: TS) {
   return args;
}

// Use like this:
const transforms = tuplify(
   {
      transformer: append,
      arg: " END"
   },
   {
      transformer: repeat,
      arg: 4
   },
);

//And call apply transforms like this:
applyTransforms("string", ...transforms)

//or like this:
applyTransforms("string", transform1, transform2)
```

### Explanation

Typescript has really powerful type inference, but usually chooses the loosest types it can. In this case you need to force it to think of your transforms as a Tuple so that each element has it's own type, and then let the inference do the rest.

I did this with mapped types, the one hiccup with this is that Typescript will use all the tuple keys (such as "length"), not just the numeric ones. You just need to force it to only map the numeric ones. Hence the condition:
`T[P] extends T[number]`