# Defining an array of differing generic types in TypeScript

Tags: arrays, typescript, generics

```
interface Instruction {
  promise: Promise<unknown>,
  callback?: ($html: JQuery, data: unknown ) => void
}

const arr: Instruction[] = [
  { promise: Promise.resolve({ foo: 'bar' }), callback: ($html, data) => console.log(data.foo) },
  { promise: Promise.resolve({ bar: 'foo' }), callback: ($html, data) => console.log(data.bar) }
];
```

Given the above, I'd like TypeScript to recognise that the data parameter in the callback function is of the same type as the resolution of the Promise.

If it was stand alone, I could do:

```
interface Instruction<T> {
  promise: Promise<T>,
  callback?: ($html: JQuery, data: T) => void
}
```

But then how would I define the array, where `T` can mean something different on each line?

Comment: In your actual code, will `arr` be an immutable array of a length and type known at compile-time?

Comment: @Aplet123, no in the real code the array is constructed within a bigger class, using `push`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you define an array of generics in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51879601/how-do-you-define-an-array-of-generics-in-typescript)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is practically the canonical use case for [existential generic types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Existential_types), which are not directly supported in TypeScript (neither are they directly supported in most languages with generics, so it's not a particular shortcoming of TypeScript). There is an open feature request, [microsoft/TypeScript#14466](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466), asking for this, but it is not part of the language as of TS4.1.

Generics in TypeScript are "universal", meaning that when I say `class Foo<T> {...}` I mean that it works for *all* possible type parameters `T`.  That lets the *consumer* of a `Foo<T>` specify the value for `T` and do what they want with it, while the *provider* of `Foo<T>` needs to allow for all possibilities.

Heterogeneous collections like the one you are trying to describe require "existential" generics.  In some sense you want `interface Instruction<exists T> {...}` to mean that *there is* a type parameter `T` for which it works.  Meaning that the *provider* of an `Instruction` could specify the value for `T` and do what they want with it, while the *consumer* of an `Instruction` needs to allow for all possibilities.

For more information about universally-vs-existentially quantified generics, see [this SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292274/what-is-an-existential-type).

---

While there is no *direct* support for existentials in TypeScript, there is *indirect* support.  The difference between a universal and an existential has to do with who is looking at the type.  If you switch the role of producer and consumer, you get existential-like behavior.  This can be accomplished via callbacks.  So existentials can be *encoded* in TypeScript.

Let's look at how we might do it for `Instruction`.  First, let's define `Instruction` as a universal generic, the "standalone" version you mentioned (and I'm removing the `JQuery` dependency in this code):

```
interface Instruction<T> {
    promise: Promise<T>,
    callback?: (data: T) => void
}
```

Here's the existential encoding, `SomeInstruction`:

```
type SomeInstruction = <R>(cb: <T>(instruction: Instruction<T>) => R) => R;
```

A `SomeInstruction` is a function that calls a function that accepts an `Instruction<T>` for any `T` and returns the result.  Notice how `SomeInstruction` does not itself depend on `T` anymore.  You might wonder how to *get* a `SomeInstruction`, but this is also fairly straightforward.  Let's make a helper function that turns any `Instruction<T>` into a `SomeInstruction`:

```
const someInstruction = <T,>(i: Instruction<T>): SomeInstruction => cb => cb(i);
```

Finally we can make your hetereogeneous collection:

```
const arr: SomeInstruction[] = [
    someInstruction({ 
      promise: Promise.resolve({ foo: 'bar' }), 
      callback: (data) => console.log(data.foo) 
    }),
    someInstruction({ 
      promise: Promise.resolve({ bar: 'foo' }), 
      callback: (data) => console.log(data.bar) 
    })
]
```

That all type checks, as desired.

---

Actually *using* a `SomeInstruction` is a bit more involved than using an `Instruction<T>`, since it takes a callback.  But it's not terrible, and again, allows the `T` type parameter to appear in a way that the consumer doesn't know what the actual `T` type is and therefore has to treat it as any possible `T`:

```
// writing out T for explicitness here
arr.forEach(someInstruction => someInstruction(<T,>(i: Instruction<T>) => {    
    i.promise.then(i.callback); // works
}))

// but it is not necessary:
arr.forEach(someInstruction => someInstruction(i => {    
    i.promise.then(i.callback); // works
}))
```

Nice.

---

There are other workarounds, but an existential is what you really want.  For completeness, here are some possible workarounds that I will mention but not implement:

- give up on type safety and use `any` or `unknown` and use type assertions to get back the types you want. Blecch.
- Use a [mapped tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) where you convert a type like `[T1, T2, T3]` to the corresponding `[Instruction<T1>, Instruction<T2>, Instruction<T3>]` type.  This won't work with `push()` though, so you'd need to work around that somehow too.
- Refactor `Instruction` so as not to need/expose generics.  Whatever the consumer plans to do with an `Instruction<T>` it has to be independent of `T` (e.g., I can write `i.promise.then(i.callback)` but I can't do much else, right?), so make an `Instruction` generic function which requires a valid promise-and-callback pair to create, and returns something non-generic with whatever functionality you need and that's it.  In some sense this is a "stripped-down" existential that does not allow the consumer to access the internal promise-callback pair separately.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIgM5igVwWYAexAB4AVAPmQG8AoZB5ABykIFtgMIAuZABVYcu5CgBp6jBHAA20gEaIA1gH5eACgAmcMHF5kAlMgC8VAG6FgG2gF9atMAE8mKAMrsI6LLnxEQx5CQAShRqCHK8ImqgXngExLye2LG+IoYmyIFpVIEA3LQIxFjIGO6J3nF+RgFkoiHACZhJPsSpvG5sHo3lvsZUYb3IYVH6efmFYMhwUFBtpV3JxADaALr+ixIMJR1lCyBq1MyCnDz8R1wAdFAQJdKmEPvIMISEvADkClCvyNb6ooMy8iU6i0Oiyg0KhGkEHO0kIAHNNNo4OcnoRDD9xIxinMYs09gcWOxjrwBESLlcbncHh83qivhj-rIFAhFMCkWCCphIdDYQiQciPuj9LRlnYAPRi5AAdygwAIIDhyEIOAmZEehCgyAgAA8mNJgAg5SBrhhkAALaAQWhTKAojUAUUQZrUW06uIqA1dOzxanItSiDXdKUoYLoWOA50JQmhYAtewjUiZShGyAl0o1igwNn0wtoabkKuQcqLppAhAmxqQGAwUwc3Gt0ztUEdCGdXvmeM9OKaFSiAzDjAjUeO51jEHj50TgJZKbTUozWZ+wqAA)

Comment: @jcalz: This is amazing thank you. I think I get what's going on here, but I'm struggling with this syntax, `<T,>`. Why the comma? It appears to be declaring an unused type parameter, but I can't fathom why.

Comment: The trailing comma doesn't introduce a new parameter.  It is just to stop the compiler from getting angry in the case that you are using tsx/jsx. (in tsx/jsx mode, the compiler sees `<T>` in that position as a tag and complains).  You can remove the comma if that compiles for you.

Comment: Oh wow, okay! I can't decide if I feel more or less stupid now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it will help You:

```js
type JQuery = 'jquery'

interface Instruction<T> {
  promise: Promise<T>,
  callback?: ($html: JQuery, data: T) => void
}

const builder = <T,>(arg: T): Instruction<T> => ({ promise: Promise.resolve(arg), callback: ($html, data) => data })

const arr = [
  builder({ foo: 'bar' }),
  builder({ bar: 'foo' }),
];
```

If this array is mutable, things get complicated.

**UPDATE**

You have to add extra comma `<T,>`, becouse without `,` TS thinks that You are trying to use some sort of `react jsx` syntax.
You should use this hack only with arrow function. It works as expected with `function`.
Instead of `extra comma`, You can use `<T extends unknown>` or `<T extends {}>`

Comment: Thanks @capain-yossarian! It hadn't occurred to me to wrap the instruction like that. Could you explain what is happening with `<T,>` though? I've scoured the internet but can't fathom it. Is it some sort of shortcut?