# how to set default Function in this typescript code

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, constraints

The following code is running normally.

```
function test<T extends object, K extends keyof T, P extends (v: T[K]) => any>(
    item: T,
    key: K,
    transform: P
): ReturnType<P> {
    return transform(item[key])
}
```

but when I set a default function to param `transform` it errors

```
function test<T extends object, K extends keyof T, P extends (v: T[K]) => any>(
    item: T,
    key: K,
    transform: P = v => v
): ReturnType<P> {
    return transform(item[key])
}
```

> Type '(v: T[K]) => T[K]' is not assignable to type 'P'. '(v: T[K]) => T[K]' is assignable to the constraint of type 'P', but 'P' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '(v: T[K]) => any'.

how can I modify this code to run it normally with default method `v => v`

Comment: Why have the generic type be the whole function, rather than its return value: `function test<T, K extends keyof T, R>(item: T, key: K, transform: (T[K]) => R = v => v): R`.

Comment: At least [one of these](/search?q=%5Btypescript%5D+could+be+instantiated+with+a+different+subtype+of+constraint) should answer your question. Basically, it's what the error says: It would be possible to call `test` such that `v => v` is not a valid implementation of `transform`. You'd have to make the types of `transform`'s `v` parameter and its return type the same.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I tried with `function test<T extends object, K extends keyof T, R>(item: T,key: K,transform: (v: T[K]) => R = v => v): R ` and the error is `Type 'T[K]' is not assignable to type 'R'` Typescript tried to make T[K] = R

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to dare to use type-level computation. It's enough to write concrete types.

```
type F<X, Y> = (x: X) => Y 

function test<T extends object, K extends keyof T>(
    item: T,
    key: K,
    transform: F<T[K],any> = v => v
): ReturnType<F<T[K],any>> {
      return transform(item[key])
}
```

Inference of TypeScript is not so wise acrually. In this case, compiler can't infer well type variable `P`. In token of that, [following code is inferred correctly](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygJgBQH0Bci22AHvgIZgCeAlIgLwB8iYIAtgEYoBOdKJqMABM0RUhWp0miSrUQB+Fuy7dEhDNxhgA5g0QBGGgG8AUAF8gA):

```
function test2(_: ((x:any) => number) extends ((x:any) => any) ? number : string = 1){
}
```

There is keyword `infer` to only infer type variables all the way (and this can use **ONLY** after `extends` in typing of parameters).

Type-level computation in TypeScript is developing yet, let's look forward to it.

Comment: I tried this result and this will lose ReturnType and make `test` return `any`

Comment: currently, I use many Function delcare and some @ts-ignore to complete this action

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65129070/defining-an-array-of-differing-generic-types-in-typescript