# TypeScript: dependant type inference with variadic tuple types

Tags: typescript, types, tuples, variadic, conditional-types

**Update: it looks like for the behaviour desired, TypeScript requires existential generic types - and as if TS 4.1 it doesn't have them. Thanks the helpful answer. I think to solve the typing react-query `useQueries` there is still a way forward whereby we use `unknown` when `selector` is supplied. I'll try and make that work and see where it goes.**

Consider the following:

```
interface Data<TData = unknown, TSelected = unknown> {
    data: TData;
    selector?: (data: TData) => TSelected
}

function makeArrayAsConstItemsForDataTypesOnly<
    TItem extends readonly Data[]
>(arr: [...TItem]): { [K in keyof TItem]: { item: Extract<TItem[K], Data>["data"] } } {
    return arr.map(item => {
        return item.selector 
            ? { item: item.selector(item.data) }
            : { item: item.data }
    }) as any;
}

const returnedData = makeArrayAsConstItemsForDataTypesOnly([
    { data: { nested: 'thing' }, selector: d => d.nested },
    { data: 1 },
    { data: 'two' }])
```

`returnedData` takes the type:

```
const returnedData: [{
    item: {
        nested: string;
    };
}, {
    item: number;
}, {
    item: string;
}]
```

A `selector` may or may not be supplied with each element. If supplied, it maps over the supplied `data` type and transforms the returned data.

Given the above example, then ideally the returned type would be:

```
const returnedData: [{
    item: string;
}, {
    item: number;
}, {
    item: string;
}]
```

Alas it isn't, also, in `selector: d => d.nested`, `d` takes the type `unknown` as opposed to the type `TData`. So we aren't getting the type inference flowing through as hoped.

Pseudo-code for the return type would look like this:

- for each entry of the array:

  - get the `data` property
  - if the array entry contains a `selector` then return `{ item: entry.selector(entry.data) }`
  - else return `{ item: entry.data }`

Is it possible to express this via the type system in TypeScript? [See playground here.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQBEEQQHgCqbaoC8qArmANZgD2A7mADSp4DKUANlEtACYnkqtBgD5UAb2CppqXlgQAuFoQQBuKTIDOnbhBowA-EoAUc7EoLyAlCTFsdPKL2ABfYMDgUeIGmFQBbBEooAEEYGAQATxDNAGFfTQgASWh-TQAxfRU8SIAHKE0AeTAOSJwNaTwUqH9UKAAPaDBeTVQYKAReX1KMeQBtAF1gEWMEcKU+gDppqtSBqyVxVD6AaVRwVGDImjgWav8BxfXUpQBRRoiefH3VgeYVET6AIjMEJ4HUF0+JCraoCDIMD8Yxgk0CuWMIFSth+MjhfwBQOONUm2i4PH0qF+8JkBgkyP8SihKLRun0kNSk1eNjcOJxR2JhIJVPkn1+LhsCFaCDAkXUbmASASEARgLAThUAkCwTCEWicWF+wyWXkOXyRRKkWMfV+S1eR3FiScSgA5BAABbgADmJs+zFJGJgSn4xDEvEmhr4dt1snkSgAjN64Xq-agzXQaLaXPN3AB6ABUguFoqBEtDfUkcMZi2xMk9xtQiRg1vUcJc-OYmZk2dQYDI-gARrAK7DqydCxBi2Arfyhqh47GgA)

So there's two problems here:

- `selector` flowing through `TData` as the input
- the return type of the overall function

Comment: Do you only have a problem with `d.nested` ?

Comment: No - there's 2 problems: 1. In `selector: d => d.nested` d has the type of `unknown` as opposed to `TData`. 2. The problem stated in the question. I should probably edit it for clarity - is that what you're driving at?

Comment: Edited and mentioned above

Answer (score 2):

```js
// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type/50375286#50375286
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
  k: infer I
) => void
  ? I
  : never;

//credits goes to https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298#issuecomment-468114901
type UnionToOvlds<U> = UnionToIntersection<
  U extends any ? (f: U) => void : never
>;

//credits goes to https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298#issuecomment-468114901
type PopUnion<U> = UnionToOvlds<U> extends (a: infer A) => void ? A : never;

//credits goes tohttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/53953814/typescript-check-if-a-type-is-a-union#comment-94748994
type IsUnion<T> = [T] extends [UnionToIntersection<T>] ? false : true;

type UnionToArray<T, A extends unknown[] = []> = IsUnion<T> extends true
  ? UnionToArray<Exclude<T, PopUnion<T>>, [PopUnion<T>, ...A]>
  : [T, ...A];

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]
type MapPredicate<T> = { item: Values<T> };

// http://catchts.com/tuples
type MapArray<
  Arr extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>,
  Result extends unknown[] = []
  > = Arr extends []
  ? Result
  : Arr extends [infer H]
  ? [...Result, MapPredicate<H>]
  : Arr extends readonly [infer H, ...infer Tail]
  ? MapArray<Tail, [...Result, MapPredicate<H>]>
  : never;

type Test1 = MapArray<[{nested:42},{a:'hello'}]>[0] // { item: 42; }

interface Data<TData = any, TSelected = any> {
  data: TData;
  selector?: (data: TData) => TSelected
}

const builder = <T, R>(data: T, selector?: (data: T) => R): Data<T, R> => ({
  data,
  selector
})

type Mapper<T extends Data> = T['selector'] extends (...args: any[]) => any ? ReturnType<T['selector']> : T['data']

const first = builder({ nested: 'thing' }, d => d.nested);
const second = builder({ a: 42 });

type First = typeof first
type Second = typeof second

type Result = Mapper<First>

const arr = [first, second];

function makeArrayAsConstItemsForDataTypesOnly<T extends Data>(data: Array<T>) {
  const result = data.map((item) => {
    return item.selector
      ? { item: item.selector(item.data) }
      : { item: item.data }
  })

  /**
   * I don't know how to avoid type casting here
   * I tried different approaches, but none of them
   * helped
   */
  return result as MapArray<UnionToArray<Mapper<T>>>
}

const test = makeArrayAsConstItemsForDataTypesOnly(arr)

type ResultArray = typeof test;

type FirstElement = ResultArray[0] // { item: string }
type SecondElement = ResultArray[1] // { item: number }
```

I know, using type casting is not the best solution, but I was unable to infer generics in better way.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65129070/defining-an-array-of-differing-generic-types-in-typescript) might help you to build data structures with callback in a better type safe way

These links might help you to understand what's goin on here:

- [PopUnion,UnionToOvlds](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298#issuecomment-468114901)
- [UnionToIntersection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type/50375286#50375286)
- [IsUnion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53953814/typescript-check-if-a-type-is-a-union#comment-94748994)
- [MapArray](http://catchts.com/tuples)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer @captain-yossarian. Unfortunately in my case having the `builder` function (which I think is only to provide a type) in the mix won't work for my scenario. For context, I'm trying to strongly type the `useQueries` hook of react-query and as such I'm unlikely to be able to change the API significantly. You can see context on this PR: https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query/pull/1527#issuecomment-756125257

Comment: Incidentally, I'd say that limited use of type assertions inside a function like this is fine - and may in fact be unavoidable

Comment: Okay I've read the linked question and I think I'm asking for something that the language doesn't yet support - essentially it requires existential generic types. That is what `builder` was fulfilling. That's never going to work for the react-query use case. I think I need to pivot the question. I'll add an edit above.

Comment: @JohnReilly, yes, `builder` function is only for typings. It is an overhead, but I believe V8 will inline it. Unfortunatelly it is not that easy to infer generic of callback argument in above case. I tried to use other data structures, but without significant success. Btw, question is very good )