# Typing and validating an array of objects of unknown shape

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I spent quite some time on this and I would appreciate some help. I want a component (a function) to accept an array of objects while also validating the properties of the objects.

Interfaces and data:

```
interface ObjectWithId {
  id: string | number;
}

interface TableMeta<T extends ObjectWithId, K extends PropertyKey = keyof T> {
  data: T[];
  searchKey: K;
  onClick?: (item: T) => void;
}

interface Vegetable {
  id: number,
  label: string,
}

interface Fruit {
  id: number, 
  name: string,
}

const vegetableMeta: TableMeta<Vegetable> = {
  data: [],
  searchKey: 'label', // this only allows 'label' or 'id' 
}

const fruitMeta: TableMeta<Fruit> = {
  data: [],
  searchKey: 'name', // this only allows 'name' or 'id' 
  onClick: (item) => {item.id} // ✔️ has correct item type <---------------
}

const metas = [vegetableMeta, fruitMeta];
```

A component (a function for simplicity):

```
const metaParser = (metas: TableMeta<{id: number | string}, PropertyKey>[]) => {
  const id = metas[0].data[0].id; // should be `number | string`
}

metaParser(metas); // ❌ Type 'ObjectWithId' is not assignable to type 'Vegetable'
```

**The shape of objects in the array is unknown in advance**

Any ideas on how to make it work?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=32&ssc=42&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWEFgOrBgAWAkgCbIDeAUMssGQFzIDOYUoA5sgD7IgBXALbpoAbmoBfatVCRYiFABU46ADYQAshDBwAPEuQQAHpBBkWaLDnyFSZADTIA0kdMRzlgApQA9gAdoMABPZwhg5ABeZABrcN8YZCUAPipaZDI4XWYlAG0AXQk6Fgg4KAQiMODmZyLkXxAAYTVgBBiAfmYACkIIIRyASijUgDdfBglpWXBoeCRkADUITh1VDTS6BmZBEWgHdLVVCDVmNg4QTn2puVnFZAAxKAFCDfomfmFRKCd0kDghCCndhcK4yBANNjIEbLVbqLSrHJreG6PRLFa6OGpaI0OiZbLIAr7YqlcqVcLMADkh1EagpTgA9PTkMRgJYGmoInA1GpfAB3SxUo60+pQZAUhgU5CAXg3ALI7UjBELAyBgT0I2nxKjh6v0j2eYCxrzxcGYhPSJTKFSqlL+ALpyEZzKIrPqIA5yC5PP5YptEElvlF4rIktl6QazVaMW6vSEQ0iqUo0YAdAxJPamYAUckA8H-IIhwSzgqBQGz0SBCZnBQLIPQAWlrdfrDfl1HBIEhAN0lmiuWh6KR2qcKr12sKMmbiuQ7bgXjKJVF0S6k5YiK1qz0GGwuAIxHITh8ASCoXCyQKsfj6RbkIYUQnqxYuQADPlE0aH0+JmnWERfAI1BRRMgAAMdi+XhWGBC4AKbSdpygWcF1vAYxCAA)

Comment: Please take a look on this article if you want safe typings for callback https://catchts.com/callbacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to make it work is to expose the type of the callback and make it more generic when dealing with a collection of objects.

```
interface ObjectWithId {
  id: string | number;
}

interface TableMeta<
  T extends ObjectWithId,
  K extends PropertyKey = keyof T,
  F extends (item: never) => void = (item: T) => void, // <--- expose the type
> {
  data: T[];
  searchKey: K;
  onClick?: F;
}

interface Vegetable {
  id: number,
  label: string,
}

interface Fruit {
  id: number, 
  name: string,
}

const vegetableMeta: TableMeta<Vegetable> = {
  data: [],
  searchKey: 'label',
}

const fruitMeta: TableMeta<Fruit> = {
  data: [],
  searchKey: 'name',
  onClick: (item) => {item.id}
}

const metas = [vegetableMeta, fruitMeta];

                                                make it more generic ---⌄
const metaParser = (metas: TableMeta<ObjectWithId, PropertyKey, (item: never) => void>[]) => {
  const id = metas[0].data[0].id;
}

metaParser(metas);
```

Answer (score 0):

**THIRD UPDATE**

```js
type Base = { id: number | string } & { [p: string]: unknown }

interface Data<T extends Base> {
  data: Array<T>;
}

interface SearchKey<T extends Base> {
  searchKey: Exclude<keyof T, 'id'>;
}

type TableMeta<T extends Base> = Data<T> & SearchKey<T>

/**
 * AFAIK, this is the required overhed to be able correctly infer the types
 */
const builder = <T extends Base, K extends Exclude<keyof T, 'id'>>(searchKey: K, data: Array<T>): TableMeta<T> => ({ data, searchKey });


const metas = [
  builder('name', [{ id: 2, name: 2 }]),
  builder('key', [{ id: '2', key: 'John Doe' }]),
  // builder('hello', [{ id: 3, age: 42 }]) //expected error
];

const metaParser = <T extends TableMeta<Base>>(metas: Array<T>) => {
  const result = metas // T[]
  const result2 = metas[0].searchKey// string | number
  const result3 = metas[0].data[0].id// string | number
  return metas
}


const result = metaParser(metas); // ok
```

[Here](https://catchts.com/callbacks) you can find more info about typing callbacks.
I'm not sure if it possible to implement this without helper builder function.

You can consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65129070/defining-an-array-of-differing-generic-types-in-typescript#answer-65129942) answer, but still you have to use extra function, even two

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response! As I mentioned in the question the shape of objects is unknown in advance. It could be a Fruit and a Vegetable, but it could be something completely different. The function is a reusable component.

Comment: Your solution works @captain-yossarian, thanks! Maybe I will have to use a builder, but I would prefer not to. I have a solution that works with my original code, but once I added a callback function that depends on type `T` it broke again. I will try to make it work. I've added a link to TS Playground.