# How to enforce consistent type within objects (Typescript)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I've gotten this far: which seems to work

```
function test<types extends Record<string,any>>(dict: dictionary<types>){}

type dictionary<types extends Record<string, any>> = {
  [key in keyof types]: {
    bar?: types[key];
    foo?: (value:types[key])=>true;
  };
};

test({
 key1:{
  bar: 2,
  foo: (input:number)=>true,
 },
 key2:{
  bar: 'hello'
  foo: (input: number)=>true, // Error! "input" needs to be string
 }
})
```

BUT!
I also need a generic type reference to the `dict` parameter. And for some reason, this *doesn't* work

```
function test2<
  types extends Record<string,any>,
  dictionary extends dictionary2<types> // <-- Added a generic type
>(dict: dictionary){}

// Same as above
type dictionary2<types extends Record<string, any>> = {
  [key in keyof types]: {
    bar?: types[key];
    foo?: (value:types[key])=>true;
  };
};

// Same as above
test2({
 key1:{
  bar: 2,
  foo: (input: number)=>true,
 },
 key2:{
  bar: 'hello', 
  foo: (input:number)=>true,// Should be an Error (but isn't)! "input" needs to be string
 }
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-I8FTNG8Hx4r83aApS6BghCsC0nCCLHIyKJShizTYnh5D4oSxKksy5JAisVIQhR9LUcilisgAytgiCCOsppwvkmAclyZC8gKQqEC60mPlKvCykAA)

Comment: Please consider [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJR3vW) example. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69909166/when-declaring-an-array-of-generic-items-how-can-i-allow-the-generic-parameter/69909668#69909668) is related question. There are drawbacks. You need to use methods because they are bivariant. Let mew know if it works. If you know upfront your values, you can use [this](https://catchts.com/callbacks#callback_in_union%202) example. However, the best approach is to use builder function. It is easy, readable and safe

Comment: Builder example-> [here](https://tsplay.dev/w2EobW))

Answer (score 1):

You could do like this:

```
function test2<T extends Record<string, unknown>>(dict: Dictionary<T>) { }

type Dictionary<T> = {
  [key in keyof T]: {
    bar?: T[key];
    foo?: (value: T[key]) => true;
  };
}

// Same as above
test2({
  key1: {
    bar: 2,
    foo: (input: number) => true,
  },
  key2: {
    bar: 'hello',
    foo: (input: number) => true, // Actual error
  }
});
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygJgDwBVEoAeqYAJmogEooRwBOp2GdMYA5gDSLgDWYcAdzAA+YQApSMaAC5EAESmwEAQzoBPPMICUiAN6IAvgFgAUKahqADinmL4YVRtzDEAXj2nEiANo8UaxFZEPzU4YERcAF1ZXU8vRAAjVQB+WVxff0iAbjivYDg4VMQxADdlABsQFDSMtUidVxcoOiqcky8DNuMzEwB6XsQAZWUAWxtlCmUEuBKUc3QsMVj24P8ARhjcxNVZTA4t-LhZMVZLEChZMBARhJQ6BqaWlH2VgxevEMxNla8kulkAOQACxQ5XKcAB73ih2Op3Ol2ut3ubkeVS4-UQAEFoCAKgQ6HR6HFugYtFkgA)

Comment: Seems to be there was a much simplier solution than I thought. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

Change the inference scope so that `types` is inferred and `dict` is typed based on that inference rather than a second type parameter, i.e.,

```
function test2<
  types extends Record<string,any>
>(dict: dictionary2<types>){}
```

Working playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTCSHIDcFMAIHMD2AXZ0B2tkAsCWBnWAMwEMAnALlgHc8BjbGxMga3wDpOBYAKF96IBXdHWS5EmNPmQAeZAE8ADtELQAHmnQATQgCVodZlpnSyudPAA0JdPIB8dgBRbcoqi9Hj05eXKUq7AEoAbwBffh4FZVgPMQkfP2VVDQwdWH1DMmNTcytYG3s7WABeWGDeWFgAbRZoeVhzWFr5RCIsf3wAXSpynkrKgCNyAH4qKJUaus6Abgr%20okREUdhHSBIAG0FoCnH8SflOwOK7ZDIt2b7YUIvriKlkR16muoBGCifYIcpYACZLOYWiCojnMikEyAo6EEAFsBtAyEcTmdoP8%20qFUc95D93nMvlRwNhoOt1ohwADFsDQeCqFDYfDEactpZYCBYABRMhkZgAQlgADloNA0shEJ84DkLBVwjxQoEIhFgAAqRW8ABCAFUACrc3igfLrfCi9CCrT5BAYeGudrRMjQIjwjB0OAirCE2AAA1i7tginIJGh0DQZHYsAAgtpiMxYIaA7BbSRDehmTgCLBFVpECp0OBkIqmKxeIrgBEhCI4pIVMgfjI5rtYOpNGkMkYTKdctZbHZUU5Yu5XOWfNXdkEwnd-DF%2015B4kVPWUto9AYWxK8gUHCUynN9g1MM1WtaVN1N5dBiMxh19jM5pVActVhstjsL81DsdGdALpVbjKLrx7j9HgqZo3g%20PFfgxSMgRWKkIVgWk4QRN9kQxdEgLqbFQPIfFCWJUlmXJKCQXQMEIXg%20kkKZVkOS5Mh8mSZRRCFKVeFlIA).

EDIT:  Example usage with conventional capitalization

```
function test2<
  T,
>(dict: Dictionary<T>){

  type FullDictionary = Dictionary<T> // can't you just use this in your function?

}

type Dictionary<T extends Record<string, any>> = {
  [K in keyof T]: DictionaryEntry<T[K]>
}

type DictionaryEntry<T> = {
  bar?: T
  foo?: (value:T)=>true
}

test2({
 key1:{
  bar: 2,
  foo: (input: number)=>true,
 },
 key2:{
  bar: 'hello', 
  foo: (input:number)=>true
 }
})
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this is the same as the code I currently have isn't it (i.e. given at the top of my question)

Comment: oh, ha.  but then i guess i'm confused at what your question is.  why can't you just use `dictionary<types>`?  btw, its common to write this code with capitalized types for readability, e.g.: `function test<T extends Record<string,any>` and `type Dictionary =` etc.

Comment: I need a generic reference to the `dictionary` type to check if certain properties exist

Comment: but anywhere you want to use that generic, can't you just use dictionary<types>?  i've edited my answer to show what i mean. in my edited answer, isn't `FullDictionary` giving you what you want?  what what a generic type parameter allow you to do that you can't do with that? (sorry if i'm being dense)