# How to stored different typed functions under the same object key?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I store values and individual typed functions in an array of objects. When looping the array all the types of all typed functions in the array are required for any value. How can I write it more specific?

[ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQ4YwewOwZwF2AQwE7MQTwCoQMp2QJZQDmwAvMABQrEBcw8hJA2gLoCU9jRpZAfEmTEAdACsIRSgCIANMCnsAUKHDR4wAEYQIAGwCmiKNjxNeVGvS26DUTg3w9yA6kOAB+eej0wpwelKgIBUVFSFgEABNEOERyYGYAb2VgADdEHQBXPXp8LJlk5D0oCL1kS219Q2MHEmSAX3yQJJU0zOz4qURZKQ0pVkbQQuLS+hQ0LFwa4nrFVhComOEAW0QAB0oCOD0lp2bgTe3hIZLkDa2l4VaspTr2IA)

**TS ERROR**

Argument of type 'boolean | string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string[] & boolean'.

Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'string[] & boolean'.

```
const arrayToString = (arg: string[]): string => arg.join(", ")
const booleanToString = (arg:boolean): string => (arg ? "yes" : "no")

const data = [{
  value: true,
  render: booleanToString
  },
  {
    value: ["a","b"],
    render: arrayToString
  }
]

data.map(item =>{
  item.render(item.value) // ts error
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When declaring an array of generic items, how can I allow the generic parameter be inferred?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69909166/when-declaring-an-array-of-generic-items-how-can-i-allow-the-generic-parameter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a shortcoming of Typescript and a design limitation. It correctly types `item.value` as `boolean | string[]` and conversely it correctly types `item.render` as `typeof arrayToString | typeof booleanToString`. However, in order to ensure type-safety, Typescript doesn't know which function it is, so to guarantee it will not error on either, it intersects the parameters, hence `boolean & string[]`. The intersection of these two primitives is `never`. This is because Typescript types doesn't have iterable discrimination.

A possible workaround is to cast it as `never`

```js
data.map(({value, render}) =>{
  render(value as never);
})
```

My recommendation (if you are setting data this way) is to create a type to ensure that render always accepts the associated value as parameters

```
type ObjectWithRender<T> = {
  value: T
  render: (arg: T) => string
}

const data: [
  ObjectWithRender<boolean>,
  ObjectWithRender<[string, string]>
] = [
  {
    value: true,
    render: booleanToString
  },
  {
    value: ["a","b"],
    render: arrayToString
  }
]
```

Or alternatively create a helper function to infer value and renderValue... But this carries some downsides, namely your functions will now have to accept readonly args. It'll also affect compilation-to-runtime with an effectively useless function.

```
function validateData<T extends ReadonlyArray<any>>(data: {
  [K in keyof T]: {
    value: T[K]
    render: (arg: T[K]) => string
  }
}
) {return data}

// Will throw an error if value isn't the render arg
const validatedData = validateData(
  [
    {
      value: true,
      render: booleanToString
    },
    {
      value: ['a', 'b'],
      render: arrayToString
    }
  ] as const
)
```

[View on TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w1PQKW)

Answer (score 0):

One way around this is by declaring the argument as an intersect type:

```js
render(item.value as boolean & string[]) // no error
```

This tells the compiler to accept both types. It works much like polymorphic behavior because the type includes both possibilities.