# Typescript type check on array of subtype with generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

How can I make an array of subtypes, if the base class has a Generic parameter?

The following code illustrates what I'm trying to archive:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAFWvAPAgfHAvHA3qASADsYB3ACgDpqBDAJwHMBnALjhqIgG0BdASjYJQAX1ChIsOABEaYGtjyEuANxoAbAK4w2TMHQCWRBjzYcIAbhFjwyOAGEA9gFsoDkkTBo4MAB5gYRAAmTNKyNJg4+CAEgWGCliCiIKAA9ClwAMbOru5gcACM4rYAshCOLm4BYDJyClEE+oFsRBpOAEYwdAlJGWo0TCGl5TlVcPouajBOVSHDlR4oQ9nz1WGY9bG1kYQNTXAADIRJSanpWRW5cABMRZJLF1VXNfLb0XQwTA4adBnacLoGIzdUC9fqDMrLXJXMYTKYzeyQqqLCEPDxPNaKaKbF6YggEd6fb6-NgAchJcCOVmSIDStNpcAAgggEABRYoABQK1gk8DmuQASjAGPoARA6oQ+h01Do9IYGAAaQjnEYeQTIFB8pHPdDoRVYmAAMxoGjUqzkbHIfGwmGeVJBbl0mURHlYCNRYEFwtFvAUXEI9QIkpg0rgJJZPhosIKJL1eOVKzY9xVYFjMUNxtNzwtVqwmHIOwIAbxjVJ+SuAGZyWkxoF-gALL5qWsddgZMAadRqMXyFrtTryuBtDR5HljEJEBx5DJ1mAZADWMECBaSeL4R1jAaDIbDEajVxjO3juUTKOTV1TgXTJrNNGz1rg+eieNwJdDZcrK4Ia+iSR41jpdKMsybLsgg1zcrYmoeJ6Ip6BAVxoBEuJbjKgIKkqzpgGqsAaphiG6oQl5GteWYPjmmBCIk1hZEQjpHjMVxsFBHpCrBdDwSg2o+jgfrRJuNBSqS4aRlAkzRqm9GqnASYrBeV6ZnEZH3o+eKFgWuylhWVbpI09aNs28A0G2HZqF27BwL2HR0AOQ4jrYIoWZOmQzvOi7Ljs34EMIG47ChobCXuB5PpJWHSaeKznjsREZjed65g+BYvnsJLviSn6eb+-4AdWTKshyYHlhBki+HoRlgAA4gEnT6BkaDIEhSDFX4ATBG6yYoIYBqdHAAAamAAPy9XAzQwMonRFbymEwaK5bitEfkAnKsYhV4JUtSE2qWsNiDqsx+GxtFJGKVt8UlXQZWVSQBi1WdF1VddKCCu2dBEI1MC4e601weWXAkiFJI8Dq6B2iANF0ZhTDlkxU2sTN3FwLxalPn5O4iWJ+RBXGmFxZgMm5AO1YkrgNbNK0VnmHAwjkg5YL6AwRACWJYAOHAYAzk6tGlYYeQOAarO2CSCAxoOw6hkLTomgZYycxwYD6LIi5wKQ+hs+ZgT6AaXXvB4-waG0o68xzAI0NzobPCSUXybFSnxSpz7qa+KVaXA1ZvaGi1GNT45ObT9OM-AzP85IJIkGNdAkpQ7lPhloB-tSQA)

Full code:

```
type Type <T> = {
    new(...args: any[]): T
}

type Data = {
    [value: string]: any;
}

type Component<T extends Data> = {
    data: T;
}
```

component 1

```
type MyComponentData = {
    id: number;
}
class MyComponent implements Component<MyComponentData> {
    data = {
        id: 0
    }
}
```

component 2

```
type MyComponent2Data = {
    resource: string;
}
class MyComponent2 implements Component<MyComponent2Data> {
    data = {
        resource: '' 
    }
}
```

Attempt 1:
id should be actually a number, but type is not checked

```
type ComponentRegistry = {
    label: string,
    component: Type<Component<Data>>,
    defaultData: () => Data
}

const components: ComponentRegistry[] = [
    {
        label: 'Example 1',
        component: MyComponent,
        defaultData: () => (
            {
                id: '123'
            }
        )
    },
    {
        label: 'Example 2',
        component: MyComponent2,
        defaultData: () => (
            {id: '123'}
        )
    }
]
```

Attempt 2:  id should be actually a number, but type is not checked

```
type ComponentRegistry2<T> = {
    label: string,
    component: Type<Component<T>>,
    defaultData: () => T
}

const components2: ComponentRegistry2<Data>[] = [
    {
        label: 'Example 1',
        component: MyComponent,
        defaultData: () => (
            {
                id: '123' 
            }
        )
    },
    {
        label: 'Example 2',
        component: MyComponent2,
        defaultData: () => (
            {id: '123'}
        )
    }
]
```

Attempt 3

line 11: '{ id: number; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Data'

```
type extractGeneric<Type> = Type extends Component<infer X> ? X : never

type ComponentRegistry3 = {
    label: string,
    component<T extends Data>() : Type<Component<T>>,
    defaultData: () => extractGeneric<extractGeneric<ReturnType<ComponentRegistry3['component']>>>
}

const components3: ComponentRegistry3[] = [
    {
        label: 'Example 1',
        component: () => MyComponent,
        defaultData: () => (
            {
                id: '123' // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
            }
        )
    }
]
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i've just added the code to the question, thanks!

Comment: TypeScript lacks direct support for *existentially quantified generics* which is what you're looking for (e.g., `Array<<∃T>(Component<T>)>` which is not valid TS syntax) so you'll need to work around it.  I'm inclined to close this as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65129070/2887218); if you don't think it is, can you spell out the difference?

Comment: I don't know how you plan to interact with an array of component registries if you don't know `T` for each one... what valid operations are there?  Setting `new r.component().data = r.defaultData()` or something?  Anyway, [this code](https://tsplay.dev/WKVpKm) is how I might approach this with the existential encoding from the other question.

Comment: I've closed the question as a duplicate; if you believe this is not appropriate, please [edit] the question to clearly distinguish this from the topic of the other one and I can vote to reopen.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz it is a duplicate, thanks!