# Array of interfaces with different generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Im having some trouble defining a generic for this specific scenarion.

I have multiple [React](https://reactjs.org/) components defined like this:

```
type ComponentFunction<T> = (props: T) => void;

interface FooProps {
  bar: string;
}

const Foo: ComponentFunction<FooProps> = ({ bar }) => {};
```

and I want to have an `interface` that would look something like this:

```
interface Component<T> {
  element: ComponentFunction<T>;
  props: T;
}
```

what I would like is to have an array of those components without having to define the generic for each and every one of them. It would just be automatically "detected" from the passed `element`, for example:

```
const components: Component<?>[] = [
  {
    element: Foo,
    props: {
      bar: "bar"
    }
  },
  ...
]
```

Is this even possible?

**Edit 1:**
Replaced `React.FC` with a more generic example `ComponentFunction`.

**Solution 1:**

```
const componentArray = <T extends any[]>(array: { [I in keyof T]: Component<T[I]> }) => array;

const components = componentArray([
  {
    element: Foo,
    props: {
      bar: "string"
    }
  },
  ...
]);
```

**Solution 2:**

```
type SomeComponent = <R>(cb: <T>(component: Component<T>) => R) => R;

const someComponent = <T,>(component: Component<T>): SomeComponent => cb => cb(component);

const components: SomeComponent[] = [
  someComponent({ element: Foo, props: { bar: "string" } }),
  ...
];
```

Thanks to [@jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz) for providing the solutions.

Comment: Not really sadly. Maybe the example was too React specific. I will update it. The biggest issue I'm having with this is how to avoid defining the generic here `Component<?>[]`

Comment: This is a canonical use case for *existentially quantified generics*, which TS doesn't have direct support for (but neither do most languages, so it's not a problem with TS per se).  Your choices here are either to make everything generic and map over an array type, or to emulate existentials.  [This playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wRGl1N) shows both approaches.

Comment: See [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65129070/defining-an-array-of-differing-generic-types-in-typescript) for more information.

Comment: @jcalz Thank you! Visually it's not the nicest solution but sadly it's the only solution. For my case I prefer to make everything generic.
Also very nice explanation on [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65129070/defining-an-array-of-differing-generic-types-in-typescript)!

Comment: @jcalz Interesting issue with both solutions. If I define `FooProps` as `interface FooProps { bar: "a" | "b" | "c" }` I get an error `Type '"string"' is not assignable to type '"a" | "b" | "c"'.`

Comment: That has to do with type inference from string literal values and has nothing to do with heterogeneous arrays, so it doesn't seem to be in scope for this question.