# Typescript type for validly indexed tuples?

Tags: typescript, types, union-types

I've been trying to develop typing for a flow based system, where the outputs of nodes in the flow must go into the "correct" input of another node. Each node is implemented as a `FlowNode<Inputs extends any[], Output extends any>`.

For this to be validly typed, each flow node can only output to a link of the type:

```
type ValidLink = [FlowNode<OtherInputs, any>, I]
// where
//   I extends number
//   OtherInputs[I] extends Output
```

It's possible to simplify this problem to the problem of implementing the generic type:

```
type ValidlyIndexed<X> = [Tuple, I]
// where
//   Tuple extends any[]
//   I extends number
//   Tuple[I] extends X
```

For example, all of the following should be valid typescript:

```
[[boolean, number],                 0        ] extends ValidlyIndexed<boolean>
[[number, boolean, number, string], 0 | 2    ] extends ValidlyIndexed<number>
[['a' | 'b', string, 'b', 'c'],     0 | 1 | 2] extends ValidlyIndexed<'b'>
```

How could `ValidlyIndexed<X>` be implemented in typescript?

If it's any help, the solution [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBAKg9gOQK4FsBGEBOAeAygPigF4pcoIAPYCAOwBMBnKAAwBIBvASxoDMsoE5KrUZQaqDJgC+zKAH4BUAFxiIANywBYAFChIUAJL1OAYwgMA8j2wANADSwkYADbRK1ekwCGNEAG0AXUISdh0ocKg-AyhuKABrCBA4HkcXCACVGyEPURgnVyiA+VhECSxsA0IVGnUtbSk-cXQsAJ0dPWg8tIAZbjjsCyRgMCGHLtcAVRpOOBpg1Mnp2eyRb19A4r9xiCmZmgcjOlNzKwGhkeAx-J2luaLq2sx28GgEOGBcJEwIAAk4AHd4DAXjAABacJgkJA0OI0AE0Z76ABqXmcnDovRhZ2GQ3m20x-UGOMuAnen2+f0BcGBkDBEPwQA) is pretty close, but I'm not sure how to represent a union of all tuple types.

If there's any ambiguities with this question, feel free to leave a comment and I'll try my best to clear them up.

Comment: An example with some real values would help a lot here to understand what you need.

Comment: There's no such thing as "union of all tuple types"; essentially you want an [existentially quantified generic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65129942/2887218), but they don't exist in TS.  You can emulate them but it's probably not what you want to do.  You'll need to use regular generics and then infer them or validate them, as @AlexWayne's answer describes

Comment: @jcalz: Thanks for the link, it's very helpful as to why this doesn't work (and should hopefully help me avoid trying this kind of type in future...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A type can't declare relationships between its sub types without having access to that actual type.

Which means that this:

```
[[boolean, number], 0] extends ValidlyIndexed<boolean>
```

Can never be true because `ValidlyIndexed` can't see the `[[boolean, number], 0]` type.

So `ValidlyIndexed` needs to receive the type it's checking as a generic type parameter. And once you do that, you can verify that it's right with a second generic constraint.

```
type ValidlyIndexed<T extends [unknown[], number], X extends T[0][T[1]]> = T
```

This type accepts your indexed tuple as `T` and a type to verify at the indexes.

This:

```
X extends T[0][T[1]]
```

Will only allow the types at the mentioned indexes to be valid.

- `T[0]` gets the first element of `T`, the inner tuple.
- `T[1]` gets the flagged index (or index union)
- And so `T[0][T[1]]` indexes the inner tuple by flagged indexes, which provides a union of the types at those indexes.

Now it's a type error if the `X` type you are checking is not correct:

```
type A1 = ValidlyIndexed<[[boolean, number], 0], boolean> // fine
type A2 = ValidlyIndexed<[[boolean, number], 1], boolean> // Type 'boolean' does not satisfy the constraint 'number'.(2344)
type A3 = ValidlyIndexed<[[boolean, number], 1], number> // fine

type B1 = ValidlyIndexed<[[number, boolean, number, string], 0 | 2], number> // fine
type B2 = ValidlyIndexed<[[number, boolean, number, string], 0 | 2], string> // Type 'string' does not satisfy the constraint 'number'.(2344)

type C = ValidlyIndexed<[['a' | 'b', string, 'b', 'c'], 0 | 1 | 2], 'b'> // fine
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwJYBMEgJIDsUQB4QoA8AKlPsBDgM5QDaArlgNZYD2A7lnQLoA0ULAwC2AIwgAnflAAa5PJRpQSdAAw86KgIw8eAPigBeZQFgAUOdCQoAQS1HYiVOmy4CxOnVFs2CCHCwBITFJaXUBb19-LAMAelioADMkLAhLcGgbACYHeGQ0TBx8QiJPSL8AoJFxKQEdCJ8KmKh45QyoAHJy6I6oFDYIWnZgKGo4YCRqRJAoYAALaABjNixqYAk4FJGO4JqOgDoACiyAZgAWM4BKdOsbE9ynAtdijy9G6KqQ2qh6wWrJOIJZKpcw3aAAIXsxjyzkKbhKnl2kgaUUqfy+AjWEhSAHMwlAAD5QLLSJESQFJFJpMxWCE5aGPFxFdylOhklFNT41THrXH4okknnYrA4ikkdodLG43r9QaCNgjMYTKYzeZLFZYzZYbZkg7Hc5XUE09oAYQe+SZ8NeHTgvSJXQ6QtxAgdLsWHX5P0JxOkDopwIgQA)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks!
Is it possible to form an Array where each type satisfies this, or no?