# How to Preserve Generic Types in TypeScript When Implementing a Queue for Async Requests

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm working on a class to control concurrency for front-end requests using TypeScript. My implementation involves a private waiting queue, but I'm facing a challenge with defining the queue's type. I believe the type should depend on the return value of the request method (e.g., requestProfile). However, TypeScript seems not to support this kind of generic type passing, resulting in loss of the generic type in the #execWaitingQueue function. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
async function requestProfile(uid: string): Promise<string> {
  // Simulate a user profile request
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(`UserProfile-${uid}`);
    }, 1000);
  });
}

// A more elegant implementation
type QueueMember<T> = {
  toRequest: () => Promise<T>;
  resolve: (value: T | PromiseLike<T>) => void;
  reject: (reason?: any) => void;
};
class AsyncLimitQueue {
  #limit = 7;
  #waitingQueue: Array<QueueMember<any>> = [];

  constructor(limit?: number) {
    this.#limit = limit ?? this.#limit;
  }

  #execWaitingQueue() {
    if (this.#limit === 0 || this.#waitingQueue.length === 0) return;

    // Todo--toRequest, resolve lose generic type <T>
    const { toRequest, resolve, reject } = this.#waitingQueue.shift()!;
    this.#limit--; // Decrement the semaphore
    toRequest()
      .then(resolve)
      .catch(reject)
      .finally(() => {
        this.#limit++; // Increment the semaphore
        this.#execWaitingQueue(); // Try executing requests in the waiting queue
      });
  }

  inQueue<T>(toRequest: () => Promise<T>): Promise<T> {
    return new Promise<T>((resolve, reject) => {
      // All requests enter the queue first
      this.#waitingQueue.push({
        toRequest,
        resolve,
        reject,
      } as QueueMember<T>);
      // Attempt to execute the waiting queue
      this.#execWaitingQueue();
    });
  }
}

async function loadUserProfiles() {
  const start = new Date().getTime();
  const uids: string[] = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"];
  const queue = new AsyncLimitQueue(5);
  const profiles = await Promise.all(uids.map((id) => queue.inQueue(() => requestProfile(id))));
  console.log(new Date().getTime() - start > 2000 && new Date().getTime() - start < 3000, profiles);
}

loadUserProfiles();
```

In this setup, #waitingQueue is an array of QueueMember, which leads to the loss of generic type  in toRequest, resolve, and hence in the entire flow of the queue operation. I would like to keep the generic type intact throughout the process, so the queue can support different request functions with different return types.

Could someone guide me on how to solve this issue of generic type loss? Is there a pattern or TypeScript feature that I'm missing that could help retain the generic type information?

Comment: TS can't track arbitrary *mutations* of types, so if that queue is constantly having things pushed onto and shifted off of it, you're never going to be able to have the compiler really keep track of it. But I'm confused, where does it matter that these are being tracked? Inside the body of `AsyncLimitQueue`? Or from the caller's side?

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for your response. I am a TypeScript novice, practicing with some code exercises. In my vision, I hoped to track types within the main body of `AsyncLimitQueue`. However, as you mentioned, it's indeed a fact that tracking the queue's entries and exits is not feasible. So, I would like to ask, in this case, how should I go about setting TypeScript types? Or should I simply use `any`?

Comment: It seems like you're looking for a heterogenous array of the sort described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65129070/2887218).  You can use `any` and it will more or less work fine. If you care about trying to maintain type safety more you could use an encoding of existential generics as described there too, which looks like [this version of your code](https://tsplay.dev/wOKX7w). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll either write up an answer or find an appropriate duplicate target. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @ jcalz Wow! What a clear explanation! Thank you for your reply; I think this is the answer I was looking for. The syntax <T,> is used to prevent the compiler from getting angry when using tsx/jsx, haha, very interesting knowledge.

Comment: I should delve more into the essence of the problem and only include the key code when asking questions, rather than posting the entire code block like I'm doing now. Thanks again for your reply!