# Array with any generic inside

Tags: typescript, generics

I want to declare type as array of pairs containing constructor function and argument that can be passed into this constructor. And the same question about rest function arguments. How can I do it?

For example in the [following code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20ISmth%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20value%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ISmthConstructor%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20new(value%3A%20T)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20A%20implements%20ISmth%3Cnumber%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor(public%20value%3A%20number)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20B%20implements%20ISmth%3Cstring%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor(public%20value%3A%20string)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ISmthConfig%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20type%3A%20ISmthConstructor%3CT%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20config%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%20%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20f%3CT%20extends%20any%5B%5D%3E(...args%3A%20T)%20%7B%20%2F%2F%20What%20should%20I%20use%20instead%20of%20%60any%60%3F%0D%0A%20%20return%20args%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20It%20should%20array%20of%20ISmthConfig%3CU%3E%20with%20any%20%60U%60%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20x%20%3D%20f(%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20type%3A%20A%2C%20config%3A%2012%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20type%3A%20B%2C%20config%3A%20%22%22%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20type%3A%20A%2C%20config%3A%20%22%22%20%7D%2C%20%2F%2F%20I%20want%20this%20argument%20to%20be%20an%20error%0D%0A)%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20y%3A%20ISmthConfig%3Cany%3E%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%20%2F%2F%20What%20should%20I%20use%20instead%20of%20%60any%60%3F%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20type%3A%20A%2C%20config%3A%2012%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20type%3A%20B%2C%20config%3A%20%22%22%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20type%3A%20A%2C%20config%3A%20%22%22%20%7D%2C%20%2F%2F%20I%20want%20this%20line%20to%20be%20an%20error%0D%0A%5D%3B) I want  lines with `{ type: A, config: "" }` to be an error as `A` does not accept `string` as a constructor argument:

```
interface ISmth<T> {
  value: T;
}

interface ISmthConstructor<T> {
  new(value: T);
}

class A implements ISmth<number> {
  constructor(public value: number) {}
}

class B implements ISmth<string> {
  constructor(public value: string) {}
}

interface ISmthConfig<T> {
  type: ISmthConstructor<T>;
  config: T;
}; 

function f<T extends any[]>(...args: T) { // What should I use instead of `any`?
  return args;                            // It should array of ISmthConfig<U> with any `U`
}

var x = f(
  { type: A, config: 12 },
  { type: B, config: "" },
  { type: A, config: "" }, // I want this argument to be an error
)

var y: ISmthConfig<any>[] = [ // What should I use instead of `any`?
  { type: A, config: 12 },
  { type: B, config: "" },
  { type: A, config: "" }, // I want this line to be an error
];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript array of different generic types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51815782/typescript-array-of-different-generic-types)

Answer (score 2):

First: I will change your definition of `ISmthConstructor<T>` to the following:

```
interface ISmthConstructor<T> {
  new(value: T): ISmth<T>; // added return type
}
```

The version in your code returns an `any` type implicitly, which is fine I guess but doesn't seem to be your intent.

---

Today's build of TypeScript (3.1.0-dev.20180922) gives me hope that the right answer is to tell you to wait until [TypeScript 3.1 comes out sometime this month (Sep 2018)](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap#31-september-2018) and then do this:

```
declare function f<T extends any[]>(
  ...args: { [K in keyof T]: ISmthConfig<T[K]> }
): void;

// no error, T inferred as [number, string]
f(
  { type: A, config: 12 }, 
  { type: B, config: "" }
);

// error, T inferred as [number, string, string | number]
f(
  { type: A, config: 12 }, 
  { type: B, config: "" },
  { type: A, config: "" } // error on type: string is not assignable to number
);
```

This is taking advantage of the upcoming [mapped tuples](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25947) feature, as well as [inference from mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#inference-from-mapped-types).  Basically you are saying that the argument at position `K` must be an `ISmthConfig<T[K]>`.  If the compiler can infer a tuple/array type `T` that meets this criterion, then it succeeds.  Otherwise it reports an error on the offending parameter.

Anyway this is really promising!

---

If you need something that works on TypeScript 3.0, the best you're going to do is to pick some maximum reasonable length of argument list and make a function that can accommodate that:

```
function goodEnough<A0, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6>(
  ...args: [ISmthConfig<A0>?, ISmthConfig<A1>?, ISmthConfig<A2>?, ISmthConfig<A3>?,
    ISmthConfig<A4>?, ISmthConfig<A5>?, ISmthConfig<A6>?]
) {
  return args;
}
goodEnough({ type: A, config: 12 }); // okay
goodEnough({ type: B, config: "" }); // okay
goodEnough(
  { type: A, config: 12 },
  { type: B, config: "" },
  { type: A, config: "" } // error, string not assignable to number
);
```

This has the disadvantage of having an arbitrary limit and being verbose, but at least it works.

If the above signature ends up giving you an unusable type for `args` with lots of optional tuple elements, or you need something that works in TypeScript 2.9 and below, then you can do a series of [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads), which is even more verbose:

```
function ugh<A0>(a0: ISmthConfig<A0>): [typeof a0];
function ugh<A0, A1>(
  a0: ISmthConfig<A0>, a1: ISmthConfig<A1>
): [typeof a0, typeof a1];
function ugh<A0, A1, A2>(
  a0: ISmthConfig<A0>, a1: ISmthConfig<A1>, a2: ISmthConfig<A2>
): [typeof a0, typeof a1, typeof a2];
function ugh(...args: ISmthConfig<any>[]): ISmthConfig<any>[] {
  return args;
}

ugh({ type: A, config: 12 }); // okay
ugh({ type: B, config: "" }); // okay
ugh(
  { type: A, config: 12 },
  { type: B, config: "" },
  { type: A, config: "" } // error, string not assignable to number
);
```

That's functional, but, well, ugh.

---

To recap: TypeScript 3.1 will solve this nicely; wait for that (or use it now) if you can.  Otherwise, there are fallbacks/workarounds of various layers of distaste.

Hope that helps.  Good luck!