# Infer return type of sibling function

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I want to be able to do this:

```
  const columns: ColumnDefinition<Pair>[] = [
    { label: 'Pair', value: pair => (all ? pair.code : pair.second.code), format: result => result.toUpperCase() },
    { label: 'Price', numeric: true, value: pair => 0 },
    { label: 'Change', numeric: true, value: pair => 0 },
  ];
```

and have TS know that the `pair` parameter for `value` is of type `Pair` and the `result` parameter for `format` is of type `string` (`pair.code` is a `string`). Whatever `value` returns is what will be given to `format`. The return type of `value` may be different across different column definitions.

This is my type so far:

```
export type ColumnDefinition<T, F extends (item: T) => unknown> = {
  label?: string;
  numeric?: boolean;
  value: F;
  format?: (value: ReturnType<F>) => string;
};
```

but I get an error stating:

> Generic type 'ColumnDefinition' requires 2 type argument(s).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript array of different generic types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51815782/typescript-array-of-different-generic-types)

Answer (score 2):

`extends` is only part of the type definition. If you want to optionally omit the generic type, you need to set a default using `=`:

```
export type ColumnDefinition<T, F extends (item: T) => unknown = (item: T) => unknown> = {
```

Comment: Yeah, that removes the error, but now TS thinks `result` is `unknown` all the time.

Comment: @rhyek that's because you're always setting the return type as `unknown`. You could override it in the generic usage `<Pair, (item: Pair) => string>`

Comment: True, but if i do that I will not be able to declare the whole column list as a literal array as I've shown in the original question.