# Is it possible work with array's elements with different union types without "is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'" error?

Tags: typescript, generics, types, existential-type, union-types

```js
type GenericElement<T> = {
  set: Setter<T>;
  state: T;
} 

type Setter<T> = (state: T) => void

type GenericElements = Array< GenericElement<string> |  GenericElement<number>>

const genericElements = [{
  set: (state: string) => console.log(state),
  state: 'stateValue'
}, {
  set: (state: number) => console.log(state),
  state: 123
}]

genericElements.map(({set, state}) => set(state))
// ---------------------------------------|

/**
 * Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
 * Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.(2345)
*/
```

Example on [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=21&pc=1#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAcRgOxgJwJYGMCiAbGAWxTAB4AVAPjgF44BvUOOAZxjAC44BldsdCpQDcTVmACG-LuREgAvnFChIsHnwFVacABQsJUuOQCUtagDcA9hgAmS8NHhJUmXAWLIwLLQEE0acRCkiCjo2PhEJKR6mMgA5tQAPsxOoa4RHqTIAK6EAEbolJR2WBbIenCxIS7h7p5aANqMIMxsnDp6kjBc0RhxJjTUJWUWBAB0eBaxuvowRgA0oh0GAORLMABq4nhZMMugcnMMi+xc051c2Xno-YOlLCMw45Nn-POLM1wAjABMAMz7AF07JVnGE3CQWKNCOIoNptPRWoc1nIbqx2C9ZkY7EA)

Is it possible to implement it without this issue, or how to lead proposed structure to be abble to hanlde it `set(state)` in common way without boilerplates like perform this operation for each child manually or overcodes like `[() => set1(state1), () => setN(stateN)]`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I type parameterize a tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46185023/how-do-i-type-parameterize-a-tuple)

Comment: @HTNW In the answer you linked, you ended up pushing the universal quantification inside of the array, i.e. instead of `Array<Foo<string>|Foo<number>>`, one would end up with `Array<FooExistentiallyQuantified>`. Does it actually work if one has `Foo<string>|Foo<number>`? It seems that it cannot use `existentialize`-like nat trafo inside of the `map`, so one is forced to cast `Foo<string>|Foo<number>` to something like `Foo<any>`, and at that point the whole previous construction seems to become unnecessary. Are there better solutions?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Hmm, you're right. I'm not sure anything quite works for an actual `Array<Foo<string>|Foo<number>>`. I think we basically need a way to say that, since the same function typechecks on both branches, it should typecheck on the union. Right now the compiler is destroying the "correlation" between `set` and `state`. Close vote retraced.

Answer (score 0):

After of continious invastigation I found the way which can work for me.

Link to [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=26&ssc=1&pln=43&pc=53#code/KYOwrgtgBA5qwCcCWBjAKgTwA7AM5QG8BYAKCnKlwBdkQZMd8BeKAcmtvuz1YBpSKUcBABGiBnigtWwsQgm4+pAL6kUAexDVCs8d1y9KNJHQXKpseMnT6A3KVJVuUAOJXUAUQA2wCKCoAPGhQwAAeVKAAJvhwIIioCgB8FsRkFLjAVABcUADKmREIQYn2aeTUAIYROblUVcDFpcqljs619UEh4VEx7jaMySzBYREg0ZZx1goAdLry+lAA-EKQclA5HCYwLSROOHl1EcyEAhQA2nMKALo1hw2x8f14s6t6A6WCZ5um+jcHHQ8pvppt8uO8VDs9sA8gVEJ0Rj0Jo8khYABSVar-CLFACUUmSADd1EhIpC2rCEMdUp9Lr8ahSAoCEsDaeCylAvsYfow-vkqIVGX0ZqCkk0dhotFRKBTcPT+YgqadyBdXvMeTl0XdbgChSzVUk8UxkhLcOofNMvOoYJr6jj+OzOZxrhqMcBtdimU9cCCuWC8IlDcbNKbzZbra67RCHCQTVLXbKsZIWNTzqy8H8AIwAJgAzPbPiK6WxszmlCRmtGoa4+t5fP5jgBBBAICoYAJuSaeHx+ECBT1JErR2NI6y1ntUBMdx5j+sWM5KwjS7JLwretMGIz1DZ3Nf6hbKfMUAhLjYyn1O-SGV3b+rewuMKAH0hXHaeme970QCpYVGo48ZKgrzuR9AyXG0IhxHFbCAA) to play.

```js
enum genericTypes {
    stringTypes = 'stringTypes',
    numberTypes = 'numberTypes',
}
const {numberTypes, stringTypes} = genericTypes;

type GenericElement<T extends genericTypes> = {
    set: Setter<T>;
    state: State<T>;
};

type State<T extends genericTypes> = T extends genericTypes.numberTypes ? number : string;

type States = {
    [numberTypes]: State<genericTypes.numberTypes>;
    [stringTypes]: State<genericTypes.stringTypes>;
};

type Setter<T extends genericTypes> = (state: State<T>) => void;

type Setters = {
    [numberTypes]: Setter<genericTypes.numberTypes>;
    [stringTypes]: Setter<genericTypes.stringTypes>;
};

const setters: Setters = {
    [numberTypes]: (state: State<genericTypes.numberTypes>) => console.log(state),
    [stringTypes]: (state: State<genericTypes.stringTypes>) => console.log(state),
};

const states: States = {
    [numberTypes]: 123,
    [stringTypes]: '123',
};

type GenericElements = Array<GenericElement<genericTypes>>;

const genericElements: GenericElements = [
    { set: setters.numberTypes, state: states.numberTypes },
    { set: setters.stringTypes, state: states.stringTypes },
];

genericElements.map(({ set, state }) => set(state));
```

I will continue to investigate to finally understanding. If anybody could review the proposal with feedback I will be very appreciate.