# How do we overcome the compile time and runtime gap when programming in a Dependently Typed Language?

Tags: haskell, coq, agda, idris, dependent-type

I'm told that in dependent type system, "types" and "values" is mixed, and we can treat both of them as "terms" instead.

But there is something I can't understand: in a strongly typed programming language without Dependent Type (like Haskell), Types is decided (infered or checked) at **compile time**, but values is decided (computed or inputed) at **runtime**.

I think there must be a gap between these two stages. Just think that if a value is interactively read from STDIN, how can we reference this value in a type which must be decided AOT?

e.g. There is a natural number `n` and a list of natural number `xs` (which contains n elements) which I need to read from STDIN, how can I put them into a data structure `Vect n Nat`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292274/what-is-an-existential-type

Comment: @luochen1990 you are thinking of compile-time code execution, which many non-dependently-typed languages have, such as C++ and D, and which indeed cannot do what you describe. Think about a dependent type system as being able to reason about parametrized operations in the abstract, without necessarily executing them (which requires providing a concrete argument).

Answer (score 50):

Suppose we input `n :: Int` at runtime from STDIN. We then read `n` strings, and store them into `vn :: Vect n String` (pretend for the moment this can be done).
Similarly, we can read `m :: Int` and `vm :: Vect m String`. Finally, we concatenate the two vectors: `vn ++ vm` (simplifying a bit here). This can be type checked, and will have type `Vect (n+m) String`.

Now it is true that the type checker runs at compile time, before the values `n,m` are known, and also before `vn,vm` are known. But this does not matter: we can still reason *symbolically* on the unknowns `n,m` and argue that `vn ++ vm` has that type, involving `n+m`, even if we do not yet know what `n+m` actually is.

It is not that different from doing math, where we manipulate symbolic expressions involving unknown variables according to some rules, even if we do not know the values of the variables. We don't need to know what number is `n` to see that `n+n = 2*n`.

Similarly, the type checker can type check

```
-- pseudocode
readNStrings :: (n :: Int) -> IO (Vect n String)
readNStrings O     = return Vect.empty
readNStrings (S p) = do
   s <- getLine
   vp <- readNStrings p
   return (Vect.cons s vp)
```

(Well, actually some more help from the programmer could be needed to typecheck this, since it involves dependent matching and recursion. But I'll neglect this.)

Importantly, the type checker can check that without knowing what `n` is.

Note that the same issue actually already arises with polymorphic functions.

```
fst :: forall a b. (a, b) -> a
fst (x, y) = x

test1 = fst @ Int @ Float (2, 3.5)
test2 = fst @ String @ Bool ("hi!", True)
...
```

One might wonder "how can the typechecker check `fst` without knowing what types `a` and `b` will be at runtime?". Again, by reasoning symbolically.

With type arguments this is arguably more obvious since we usually run the programs after type erasure, unlike value parameters like our `n :: Int` above, which can not be erased. Still, there is some similarity between universally quantifying over types or over `Int`.

Answer (score 6):

It seems to me that there are two questions here:

1. Given that some values are unknown during compile-time (e.g., values read from STDIN), how can we make use of them in types? (Note that [chi has already given an excellent answer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48129243/377022).)
2. Some operations (e.g., `getLine`) seem to make absolutely no sense at compile-time; how could we possibly talk about them in types?

The answer to (1), as chi has said, is symbolic or abstract reasoning.  You can read in a number `n`, and then have a procedure that builds a `Vect n Nat` by reading from the command line `n` times, making use of arithmetic properties such as the fact that `1+(n-1) = n` for nonzero natural numbers.

The answer to (2) is a bit more subtle.  Naively, you might want to say "this function returns a vector of length `n`, where `n` is read from the command line".  There are two types you might try to give this (apologies if I'm getting Haskell notation wrong)

```
unsafePerformIO (do n <- getLine; return (IO (Vect (read n :: Int) Nat)))
```

or (in pseudo-Coq notation, since I'm not sure what Haskell's notation for existential types is)

```
IO (exists n, Vect n Nat)
```

These two types can actually both be made sense of, and say different things.  The first type, to me, says "at compile time, read `n` from the command line, and return a function which, at runtime, gives a vector of length `n` by performing IO".  The second type says "at runtime, perform IO to get a natural number `n` and a vector of length `n`".

The way I like looking at this is that all side effects (other than, perhaps, non-termination) are monad transformers, and there is only one monad: the "real-world" monad.  Monad transformers work just as well at the type level as at the term level; the one thing which is special is `run :: M a -> a` which executes the monad (or stack of monad transformers) in the "real world".  There are two points in time at which you can invoke `run`: one is at compile time, where you invoke any instance of `run` which shows up at the type level.  Another is at runtime, where you invoke any instance of `run` which shows up at the value level.  Note that `run` only makes sense if you specify an evaluation order; if your language does not specify whether it is call-by-value or call-by-name (or call-by-push-value or call-by-need or call-by-something-else), you can get incoherencies when you try to compute a type.