# Need help understanding how type inference works in this example

Tags: typescript

I don't understand why this very short TypeScript snippet:

```js
type R<B> = (b: B | undefined) => {};

type W = (z: Z) => Z;
type Z = <B>(r: R<B>) => B;

interface BB {someKey: number}

const result: Z = (_r: R<BB>) => ({ someKey: 123 });
```

is causing this error:

```unknown
Type '(_r: R<BB>) => { someKey: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Z'.
  Types of parameters '_r' and 'r' are incompatible.
    Types of parameters 'b' and 'b' are incompatible.
      Type 'BB' is not assignable to type 'B'.
```

Can anyone help me understand how TypeScript's type inference works here?
Here's the link to the snippet on [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20R%3CB%3E%20%3D%20(b%3A%20B%20%7C%20undefined)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20W%20%3D%20(z%3A%20Z)%20%3D%3E%20Z%3B%0D%0Atype%20Z%20%3D%20%3CB%3E(r%3A%20R%3CB%3E)%20%3D%3E%20B%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20BB%20%7BsomeKey%3A%20number%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20result%3A%20Z%20%3D%20(_r%3A%20R%3CBB%3E)%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%20someKey%3A%20123%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A)

Comment: Can you include the snippet in the question as well?

Comment: Snippet added to question.

Comment: `Z` is a generic function type, but the function you are assigning to `result` is *not* generic.  Its parameter, `_r`, can *only* be of type `R<SS>` (or is that `R<BB>`?), while a function of type `Z` needs its parameter to be `R<S>` for *any* `S`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(For ease of understanding for others, I'm going to use `Array<T>` instead of `R<B>` and `number` instead of `BB`, and I will rename `Z` to `GenericArrayPicker`.  And `W` doesn't enter in so I'm removing it. If you want to switch them back you can. The error is exactly the same, but hopefully the terminology below is more intuitive.)

Your main error is trying to say that a non-generic function is generic.  Observe the following type:

```
type GenericArrayPicker = <T>(arr: Array<T>) => T;
```

That's a *generic* function type, where the type parameter `T` is anything the *caller* of the function wants it to be.  Let's say we actually had a function of that type:

```
declare const genericArrayPicker: GenericArrayPicker;
```

The caller is free to choose `T` either explicitly:

```
genericArrayPicker<string>(["foo", "bar"]); // returns a string
```

or implicitly by allowing the compiler to infer it from the call site:

```
genericArrayPicker(["foo", "bar"]); // T still inferred as string
```

Now the following function is *not* generic:

```
const numberArrayPicker = 
  (arr: Array<number>) => 17;
```

It only works on arrays of numbers.  If you inspect its type, it is `(arr: Array<number>) => number`.  You cannot call it with strings the way you can with `genericArrayPicker`:

```
numberArrayPicker(["foo", "bar"]); // error!
```

This should be a hint that `numberArrayPicker` does not match the `GenericArrayPicker` type.  If you try to assign it to a `GenericArrayPicker`, you get a warning:

```
const result: GenericArrayPicker = numberArrayPicker; // error!
// T is not assignable to number
```

The statement "`T` is not assignable to `number`" might seem weird.  A more explicit statement is that `numberArrayPicker` only works for a value of the type parameter `T` chosen by the *implementer* of the function (`number`).  But it is the caller, not the implementer, who gets to choose the value of `T`.  This is the difference between [universal and existential type quantification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5520212/2887218); TypeScript only supports universal type quantification (caller picks a type, implementer has to accept whatever the caller picks), not existential type quantification (implementer picks a type, caller has to accept whatever the implementer picks).

Hope that makes sense.  Good luck.

Comment: I've never thought about the universal vs existential types before. Thanks for shedding light on that.