# Retaining specific result type param when calling a method with parameterised type parameter from another method with parameterised type parameter

Tags: scala, generics, inheritance, methods, existential-type

Suppose I'm attempting to model entities, metadata, and repositories using inheritance

```
trait EntityMetadata {
  def maybeVersion: Option[Int]
}

// For creation
case object NoMetadata extends EntityMetadata {
  def maybeVersion: Option[Int] = None
}

// For other cases
final case class VersionedMetadata(version: Int) extends EntityMetadata {

  def maybeVersion: Option[Int] = Some(version)
}

trait Entity[Meta <: EntityMetadata] {
  type Id
  def id: Id
  def meta: Meta // Meta is paremeterised
}
```

If I then try to create a trait to hold some methods for a general purpose backing store, it seems to me like even though the types are known...I can't actually use them properly?

```
trait BackingStore {

  // Method for retrieving an entity by id
  // `Meta` doesn't really matter here, but we can't
  // wild-card it. We return the Entity with VersionedMetadata
  // since it's been stored if we can find it
  def getFromStore[Meta <: EntityMetadata, E[_] <: Entity[_]](
    id: E[Meta]#Id
  ): Option[E[VersionedMetadata]]

  // Just for demo purposes, try to retrieve something by id
  // and return its metadata version
  def getVersion[Meta <: EntityMetadata, E[_] <: Entity[_]](
    id: E[Meta]#Id
  ): Option[Long] = getFromStore(id).map { retrieved =>
    // So far so good, we know it's E[VersionedMetadata]
    val typeTest: E[VersionedMetadata] = retrieved

    //
    // value version is not a member of _$2
    // typeTest.meta.version // complains about version
    //
    retrieved.meta.version // complains about version

  }

}
```

I'm trying to work out:

1. Why the compiler thinks that `retrieved.meta` doesn't have `.version`, or, in fact, anything really beyond what `Any`/`Object` has.
2. What I can do to make this work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to fix signatures

```
def getFromStore[Meta <: EntityMetadata, E[M <: EntityMetadata] <: Entity[M]](
  id: E[Meta]#Id
): Option[E[VersionedMetadata]]

def getVersion[Meta <: EntityMetadata, E[M <: EntityMetadata] <: Entity[M]](
  id: E[Meta]#Id
): Option[Long]
```

`E[_]` and `Entity[_]` in `E[_] <: Entity[_]` are different: `E[_]` is a [type constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246719/what-is-a-higher-kinded-type-in-scala) (i.e. you can have a type `E[M]` for every type `M`), `Entity[_]` aka `Entity[Meta] forSome { type Meta }` is an [existential type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292274/what-is-an-existential-type). Existential type doesn't have `.version` (`retrieved.meta` was of type `Any`).

---

Another way to fix your code is

```
def getFromStore[Meta <: EntityMetadata, E[_] <: Entity[_]](
  id: E[Meta]#Id
): Option[E[VersionedMetadata]]

def getVersion[Meta <: EntityMetadata, E[_] <: Entity[_ <: EntityMetadata]](
  id: E[Meta]#Id
): Option[Int] = getFromStore(id).flatMap { retrieved =>
  val typeTest: E[VersionedMetadata] = retrieved

  retrieved.meta.maybeVersion
}
```

I kept type constructor and existential type but added upper bound `<: EntityMetadata` to parameter of existential type `Entity[_ <: ...]`, which is upper bound for type parameter `E[_] <: ...`. Now `retrieved.meta` has type that is a subtype of `EntityMetadata` so it has `.maybeVersion` instead of `.version` (and `map` should be replaced with `flatMap`). Also `Long` should be replaced with `Int`.

Or you could put upper bound `_ <: VersionedMetadata` instead of my `<: EntityMetadata`. Then you could keep `.version`, `.map` and `Long`.

Comment: Thanks ! The first solution worked beautifully in my case. Really liked your type constructor explanation as well; in hindsight it makes perfect sense :)