# Why is it said that typeclasses are existential?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

According to [this link describing existential types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9473088/890991):

> A value of an existential type like ∃x. F(x) is a pair containing some type x and a value of the type F(x). Whereas a value of a polymorphic type like ∀x. F(x) is a function that takes some type x and produces a value of type F(x). In both cases, the type closes over some type constructor F.

But a function definition with type class constraints doesn't pair with the type class instance.

It's not `forall f, exists Functor f, ...` (because it's obvious not every type f has instance of Functor f, hence `exists Functor f ...` not true).

It's not `exists f and Functor f, ...` (because it's applicable to all instances of satisfied f, not only the chosen one).

To me, it's `forall f and instances of Functor f, ...`, more like to scala's implicit arguments rather than existential types.

And according to [this link describing type classes](https://wiki.haskell.org/Curry-Howard-Lambek_correspondence#Type_classes):

> [The class declaration for `Eq`] means, logically, there is a type a for which the type `a -> a -> Bool` is inhabited, or, from a it can be proved that `a -> a -> Bool` (the class promises two different proofs for this, having names `==` and `/=`). This proposition is of existential nature (not to be confused with existential type)

What's the difference between type classes and existential types, and why are they both considered "existential"?

Comment: Eh? Type classes are not considered existentials. What makes you think they are? Nothing you quoted implies anything like that to me.

Comment: @DanielWagner I'm trying to understand the sentence in the second link: "This proposition is of existential nature", for what is that "existential nature".

Comment: I think it's that eg `Eq A` means "there exists a function `(==) :: A -> A -> Bool`"

Comment: @luqui but "there exists a function `(==) :: A -> A -> Bool`" is not a qualifier, `∃ x` is not a valid proposition if we are talking about the existential quantification.

Comment: @luqui and how can I interpret the type signature of `Eq a => a -> a`? `∃ Eq a . a -> a`? where should I insert `forall a`?

Comment: @JiamingLu It doesn't work like an existential, it works more like "`forall a.` when `Eq a`, then this function exists for `a` and has type `a -> a`".

Comment: That part of the wiki looks simply wrong to me, or -at best- quite misleading. A declaration `class C a where ...` does *not* imply that there is a type `a` for which we can instantiate the class, inhabiting the methods. It is using the word "existential" quite liberally. It is similar to saying that `f :: (Int -> Bool) -> Char` assumes that "it exists some function `Int->Bool`" before generating a `Char`. I would ignore that sentence.

Comment: @Cubic I'm now curious how to express "forall a. when Eq a, then this function exists for a and has type a -> a" as a proposition.

Comment: @JiamingLu: Something like "∀a. Eq a -> ((==) :: a -> a -> Bool)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The wiki you quote is wrong, or at least being imprecise. A class *declaration* is not an existential proposition; it is not a proposition of any kind, it is merely a definition of a shorthand. One could then move on to making a proposition using that definition if you wanted, but on its own it's nothing like that. For example,

```
class Eq a where (==) :: a -> a -> Bool
```

makes a new definition. One could then write a non-existential, non-universal proposition using it, say,

```
Eq ()
```

which we could "prove" by writing:

```
instance Eq () where () == () = True
```

Or one could write

```
prop_ExistsFoo :: exists a. Eq a *> a
```

as an existential proposition. (Haskell doesn't actually have the `exists` proposition former, nor `(*>)`. Think of `(*>)` as dual to `(=>)` -- just like `exists` is dual to `forall`. So where `(=>)` is a function which takes evidence of a constraint, `(*>)` is a tuple that contains evidence of a constraint, just like `forall` is for a function that takes a type while `exists` is for a tuple that contains a type.) We could "prove" this proposition by, e.g.

```
prop_ExistsFoo = ()
```

Note here that the type contained in the `exists` tuple is `()`; the evidence contained in the `(*>)` tuple is the `Eq ()` instance we wrote above. I have honored Haskell's tendency to make types and instances silent and implicit here, so they don't appear in the visible proof text.

Similarly, we could make a different, universal proposition out of `Eq` by writing something like

```
prop_ForallEq :: forall a. Eq a => a
```

which is not nontrivially provable, or

```
prop_ForallEq2 :: forall a. Eq a => a -> a -> Bool
```

which we could "prove", for example, by writing

```
prop_ForallEq2 x y = not (x == y)
```

or in many other ways.

But the class declaration in itself is *definitely not* an existential proposition, and it doesn't have "existential nature", whatever that is supposed to mean. Instead of getting hung up and confused on that, please congratulate yourself for correctly labeling this incorrect claim as confusing!

Answer (score 2):

The second quote is imprecise. The existential claim comes with the instances, not with the class itself. Consider the following class:

```
class Chaos a where
    to :: a -> y
    from :: x -> a
```

While this is a perfectly valid declaration, there can't possibly be any instances of `Chaos` (it there were, `to . from` would exist, which would be quite amusing). The type of, say, `to`...

```
GHCi> :t to
to :: Chaos a => a -> y
```

... tells us that, given any type `a`, *if* `a` is an instance of `Chaos`, there is a function which can turn an `a` into a value of any type whatsoever. If `Chaos` has no instances, that statement is vacuously true, so we can't infer the existence of any such function from it.

Putting classes aside for a moment, this situation is rather similar to what we have with [the `absurd` function](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Void.html#v:absurd):

```
absurd :: Void -> a
```

This type says that, given a `Void` value, we can produce a value of any type whatsoever. That sounds, well, absurd -- but then we remember that `Void` is the empty type, which means there are no `Void` values, and it's all good.

For the sake of contrast, we might note that instances become possible once we break `Chaos` apart in two classes:

```
class Primordial a where
    conjure :: a -> y

class Doom a where
    destroy :: x -> a


instance Primordial Void where
    conjure = absurd

instance Doom () where
    destroy = const ()
```

When we, for example, write `instance Primordial Void`, we are claiming that `Void` is an instance of `Primordial`. That implies there must exist a function `conjure :: Void -> y`, at which point we must back up the claim by supplying an implementation.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. The connection between `Chaos` and `absurd` that you're trying to make appears to be about vacuous truths -- implications with false assumptions. But that's not an existential claim. So what exactly *is* the existential claim that you say is being made?

Comment: @DanielWagner In those cases there indeed are no existential claims, as the premises are false (there are no `Chaos` instances, and no `Void` values). That's what I tried to get across with the "If it were possible..." paragraph, though I probably should add a non-vacuous example, with `Eq` or some other class with instances, to make my point clearer. I'll look into it later.