# TypeScript: Access nested object types and associted param types inside function body?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

In this [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/PTAEEkDsBcFMCcBmBDAxrUiD29QCNYAbLAd1CzwCtZVoBnAKAEsYEV1QBhLSRJgcwA8AZWjI4AGlABBWkx50AfKADeDUBtAsm0JskKjxsAFyhDcdZviwAJgFd08UwAo6YuKfOwpaXT1OyfpB0AJSgALzKXqAMAL4MDCCgAIym3HasuBTUtMyZ7BjpmdFqmqCoWBlwTqCQdgC2BPBxDNAAngAOhZWZgfLBEartXaYA5Cyo1vWwMKOxoAA+Q50moKM2NFMz0HMJFcHQ5T3VaTx8QkXVXlKXCH0KyuGqlhrauvpepqVlmhVVCKYAAwSF6gWIgsrWeyOFxuIw+OQ8EKnf7waKRZ4-TR0Eg6VAAC2cvn6ADphrAQt8sWVUMg6BhxpBJrBprNjKDqT9rNA7PBIJjOYKNCSRXDJByhT8-plTGLYCTpdVQABqFISoXxSXlOkMjbM1k7dlayGwHl8gXGn4iklyiGWqXHAGgOUKx24AC0avtYPVPw2KDshGgpl9nO5vP5ct9ms08XiCUSYAATKYACpYfj8QgYbI0aB5aoFUDpzPZkqg6AZrOrPBYLDZ5CQFrk4tV7P3AZPFTksaV0uwXYMfZuUB96unXgCQQl6vXVv9jtKQZUrSQHR6AzuVYrspj7OmFCEel2jTg0FQhxO1xbhFBZHz2dbiLKHfY3HQAlExGQMkrSmh34dTWPcByNe1w3NV9LWtW0AKFEDZS3Mk21gABCOCfhjIV-WQQNgxib0IMjLdo1BOMEySAAFOk6HIKg81olhK0wDJvyHBRDmZIxRBwDAnmcbIwgxFckgACVIbV+SYUcVlHfEMGQeB+AabZyEQOSmFoxBWKCZ0sDk8RQSSVIIEONB0A6ehQEbOickOLB1PqNouDOAQZK6WiiVrAA3DBAF4NwAxHZCElfSSJgMGzQ43DsRB1KeLi4B46xnG7FCpEVBBYhCIzk1McBQHxZBfOs1B0DoWjmNgNB8VADoaNsFzJ34dzvGs4hIGa98ap0WiaKwVA9DgGwzCfRtho7WrFOQeo6AAfhaBMgA) i have created 2 typed objects, `toggle` and `counter` which both conform to the `Config` interface, each passing their own `State` and `Action` parameter types.

My question is, how can i access these `Config` types and their associated `State` and `Action` params inside my `createStore` function body? I have no idea how to type the argument so that i don't lose that information?

I have read through the TS docs and im thinking this is something generics might help with?

Comment: Could you put your code in the text of the question and make sure it's a [mcve]?  For example, what type is `createStore()` supposed to return? Inside the implementation of `createStore()` you wouldn't be able to get *much* more expressive than `Config<any, any>` for each property.  But from the caller's point of view it may be important to preserve the mapping from key to `Config<S, A>` for some `S` and `A`... depending on what `createStore()` returns.

Comment: Anyway this is close to a canonical use case for [existential types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292274/what-is-an-existential-type), which [aren't supported directly in TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466).  There are ways to encode existential types using regular generics, but they are clunky and you might rather just use `Config<any, any>` inside the implementation.  If you edit a use case into your code (and put your code here) I might have suggestions.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your comments @jcalz. i have a full working example here where i feel like im getting close, but im not sure how to get around the 'context is being used before its been defined' error im getting in my return.

I need it to be a key of the object i pass in, so it wont let me initialise it to an empty object?

https://codesandbox.io/s/reduxified-machine-package-qgevk

Comment: That's a different issue, isn't it?  I don't really have react/redux expertise, so I wouldn't hazard a guess as to how to fix it.   If you want to get this question here answered, you should consider putting the relevant code in the text of the question.  Good luck again!

Comment: For anyone interested, i found out how to unpack Params from a Type using this fantastic article, exactly what i needed: https://link.medium.com/nkLcM7L9GY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this article which explains how to go about extracting param values from a type.

https://itnext.io/typescript-extract-unpack-a-type-from-a-generic-baca7af14e51

This makes use of conditional types, the basic syntax is as follows:

`type ExtractState<C> = C extends Config<infer State, infer Action> ? State : never;`

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly... you can specify the types for `toggle` and `counter` like this -

```
type ToggleType = typeof toggle;
type CounterType = typeof counter;
```

And then you can inline the `obj` parameter for your function -

```
const createStore = (obj: { toggle: ToggleType, counter: CounterType  }) => {
    const { toggle, counter } = obj;
}
```

---

Edit after comments:
Something like this may help, too, if you don't always have a `toggle` and a `counter` property (i.e. the properties of `obj` are arbitrary) -

```
type CreateStoreContext = {
    [key: string]: Config<any, any>
}

const createStore = (obj: CreateStoreContext) => {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {    // Key is a string
        const config = obj[key];         // config is a Config<any, any>
    })

    // ....
}
```

The difficulty though is that you won't know what the types are for `State` and `Actions` for each property of `obj` - but at least you know it conforms to a `Config` interface.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. The problem is i want to avoid being that specific in my typing for the createStore function. This will eventually be extracted into its own npm module, so i want to be more generic and somehow capture the `Config<State,Actions>` that is passed in for each one.

Comment: Will the `obj` parameter always have a `toggle` and `counter` property? Or are the properties arbitrary?

Comment: Yeh, so the `obj` param could be made up of any key, as long as the value always conforms to the `Config` interface.