# Error when enabling Kyro Serializer with Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization, kryo

I built a pipeline with **spark** 3.3.0 using **scala**.

I was using Java Serializer till now without issue. Two days ago, I face some performance issue and tried to use Kyro Serializer instead following this [gist](https://gist.github.com/claudinei-daitx/f39d51e6ecf1e0683b21741bb1cb6f53) without success. I get the following compilation error.

> type mismatch;  found   : Array[Class[_ >: ?0(in lazy value spark)
> with (some other)?0(in lazy value spark) with (some other)(some
> other)?0(in lazy value spark) with (some other)(some other)?0(in lazy
> value spark) with (some other)(some other)(some other)?0(in lazy value
> spark) with (some other)(some other)(some other)?0(in lazy value
> spark) with (some other)(some other)(some other)(some other)?0(in lazy
> value spark) with (some other)(some other)(some other)(some
> other)?0(in lazy value spark) with
> Array[org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType]
> ...
> required: Array[Class[*]] Note: Class[* >: ?0 with ?0 with ?0
> with ?0 with ?0 with ?0 with ?0 with ?0 with
> Array[org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType] with
> org.apache.spark.util.collection.BitSet with ?0 with ?0 with
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeRow with
> Array[org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.InternalRow] with ?0 with
> org.apache.spark.sql.types.ArrayType with
> org.apache.spark.sql.types.Metadata with ?0 with ?0 with ?0 with ?0
> with ?0 with Array[org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField] with
> org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField with
> Array[org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType] with
> org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType with
> collection.mutable.WrappedArray.ofRef[_$1] forSome { type *$1 }] <:
> Class[*], but class Array is invariant in type T. You may wish to
> investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Class[_]`. (SLS 3.2.10)

It seems like a type mismatch error. But I am not a **scala** expert, so I do not know how to fix it. Can anyone help me fix this ?

Below is my code.

```
def getKyroConfig() = {
    val conf = Array(
      classOf[scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.ofRef[_]],
      classOf[org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType],
      classOf[Array[org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType]],
      classOf[org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField],
      classOf[Array[org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField]],
      Class.forName("org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType$"),
      Class.forName("org.apache.spark.sql.types.LongType$"),
      Class.forName("org.apache.spark.sql.types.BooleanType$"),
      Class.forName("org.apache.spark.sql.types.DoubleType$"),
      Class.forName("[[B"),
      classOf[org.apache.spark.sql.types.Metadata],
      classOf[org.apache.spark.sql.types.ArrayType],
      Class.forName("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.UnsafeHashedRelation"),
      classOf[org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.InternalRow],
      classOf[Array[org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.InternalRow]],
      classOf[org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeRow],
      Class.forName("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.LongHashedRelation"),
      Class.forName("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.LongToUnsafeRowMap"),
      classOf[org.apache.spark.util.collection.BitSet],
      classOf[org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType],
      classOf[Array[org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType]],
      Class.forName("org.apache.spark.sql.types.NullType$"),
      Class.forName("org.apache.spark.sql.types.IntegerType$"),
      Class.forName("org.apache.spark.sql.types.TimestampType$"),
      Class.forName("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$WriteTaskResult"),
      Class.forName("org.apache.spark.internal.io.FileCommitProtocol$TaskCommitMessage"),
      Class.forName("scala.collection.immutable.Set$EmptySet$"),
      Class.forName("scala.reflect.ClassTag$$anon$1"),
      Class.forName("java.lang.Class")
    )

    conf
  }

val spark: SparkSession = {
    val conf_spark: SparkConf =  new SparkConf()

      val kyro_config = getKyroConfig()
      conf_spark.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
      conf_spark.set("spark.kryo.registrationRequired", "true")
      conf_spark.set("spark.kryoserializer.buffer", "1024k")
      conf_spark.set("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max", "1024m")
      conf_spark.registerKryoClasses(kyro_config)

    SparkSession.builder()
      .config(conf_spark)
      .getOrCreate()
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your code compile it's enough to provide the type of `val conf` explicitly:

```
val conf: Array[Class[_]] = Array(...
```

rather than  just

```
val conf = Array(...
```

Otherwise types were inferred incorrectly.

`Array[Class[_ >: ... with ... with ....]]` and `Array[Class[_]]` are so called existential types

[What is an existential type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292274/what-is-an-existential-type)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/existential-type%2bscala?tab=Votes

Normally Scala infers types correctly but sometimes you have to provide hints.

Comment: Thank you for answering, Dmytro. 

I already tried to provide the type as you mentioned. There is no difference. It returns the same compilation error message.

Comment: @yaoviametepe Are you sure that you annotated with type `val conf` and not `def getKyroConfig`? The latter is not enough. You can annotate both `val conf` and `def getKyroConfig`. If you build your project with sbt do `sbt clean compile`.

Comment: @yaoviametepe There **is** difference. This is the code **without** type annotation and it produces compile error `type mismatch` https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/RGR9GOCJQ0C43Htypq7tNQ/2 This is the code **with** type annotation and it produces `NoClassDefFoundError` https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/RGR9GOCJQ0C43Htypq7tNQ/6 `NoClassDefFoundError` is just because of Scastie. Scastie uses Java 9+ instead of Java 8 necessary for Spark. Anyway, `NoClassDefFoundError` is a runtime exception, so the code compiles successfully, without type mismatch.

Comment: @yaoviametepe I commented out a couple of classes because I don't have them and added `.master("local")`.

Comment: you are right. I annotated `def` instead of `val conf`. I changed it and it solved my issue. Thank you.

Comment: For anyone who will have this issue with that specific gist in the future, you will also need to comment out lines with the `org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$WriteTaskResult` and `scala.reflect.ClassTag$$anon$1`  classes like @dmytro-mitin mentioned it.