# Type missmatch on Slick TableQuery

Tags: scala, generics, types, slick, covariance

I am trying to have a generic type definition that can be satisfied by slicks TableQuery type:

```
  class OrderTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Order](tag, "orders") 
     ...
  
  val orders = TableQuery[OrderTable]

  type Ta[X] = TableQuery[Table[X]]

  val orderTable: Ta[Order] = orders
```

What I want to achieve is that I have an abstract type definition in a trait that can be slick table but also something else like just a hashmap. I am getting the following compilation error:

```
found   : slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile.api.TableQuery[at.gepro.dbtemplate.OrderTable]
    (which expands to)  slick.lifted.TableQuery[at.gepro.dbtemplate.OrderTable]
 required: SlickOrderRepository.this.Ta[at.gepro.dbtemplate.Order]
    (which expands to)  slick.lifted.TableQuery[slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile.Table[at.gepro.dbtemplate.Order]]
```

I don't understand why this assignment does not work, everything uses the `PostgresProfile` api.

tried `AbstractTable` but did not work either

Comment: Probably because `TableQuery` is not covariant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `TableQuery` is invariant

```
class TableQuery[E <: AbstractTable[?]](cons: Tag => E) extends Query[E, E#TableElementType, Seq]
```

https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/v3.5.0-M2/slick/src/main/scala/slick/lifted/Query.scala#L322

It's not covariant `TableQuery[+E <: AbstractTable[?]]`.

`OrderTable` is a subtype of `Table[Order]` but `TableQuery[OrderTable]` is not a subtype of `TableQuery[Table[Order]]`

```
implicitly[OrderTable <:< Table[Order]] // compiles
// implicitly[TableQuery[OrderTable] <:< TableQuery[Table[Order]]] // doesn't compile
```

Try:

- an existential type

```
type Ta[X] = TableQuery[? <: Table[X]]
// type Ta[X] = TableQuery[_ <: Table[X]] // former syntax

val orderTable: Ta[Order] = orders
```

[What is an existential type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292274/what-is-an-existential-type)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/existential-type%2bscala?tab=Votes

- or a type with additional type parameter if necessary

```
type Ta[X, T <: Table[X]] = TableQuery[T]

val orderTable: Ta[Order, OrderTable] = orders
```

You can read about variances in Scala:

https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/variances.html